# Как сделать плавный transform.position unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда делаю так,то он просто изменяет координаты на данные+x,y.
Мне нужно чтобы он плавно добавлял.
Вот код.

```
    using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class viner : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    public GameObject obj;
    public bool w;
    public bool a;
    public bool s;
    public bool d;
    float x = 0;
    float y = 0;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {




        if (a == true)
        {

            x = x - 1;




        }
        if (d == true)
        {

            x = x + 1;
            x = x;


        }
        if (s == true)
        {

            y = y + 1;

        }
        if (w == true)
        {

            y = y - 1;



        }
        transform.position = new Vector3(obj.transform.position.x + x, obj.transform.position.y + y, -10);

        x = 0;

        y = 0;



    }
}
```

Comment: `transform.position = new Vector3(obj.transform.position.x + x, obj.transform.position.y + y, -10);
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, _endPos, Time.deltaTime * 2);`    
Как мне переопределить _endpos?

Comment: Используйте в качестве него то, что вы в вашем коде сейчас назначаете в transform.position

Comment: возможно будет полезным почитать: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4