# Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-faq

- Почему один обьект проходит сквозь другой хотя у меня есть коллайдеры на обоих обьектах?
- Почему мой персонаж во время движения проходит сквозь другой обьект, а потом его откидывает назад?
- Как реализовать передвижение персонажа в Unity3d правильно?
- Почему так часто используется передвижение через transform.position и почему это неправильно?
- Почему мой персонаж движется с разной скоростью если проседает FPS?
- Почему используя присвоение в `transform.position` используют множитель `Time.deltaTime`?
- Почему двигать персонажа через смену `transform.position` неправильно?
- Почему при использовании `Velocity` или `.AddForce()` не используется множитель `Time.deltaTime`?
- Как сделать прыжок от пола, но так что бы персонаж не мог бесконечно взлетать
- Почему когда платформа движется, персонаж стоящий на платформе остается на месте?
- Почему пуля не всегда наносит урон?

Все эти вопросы, фактически, являются одним единым вопросом, который слишком уж часто встречается у начинающих.

Заодно создал тэг `unity3d-faq`

Comment: @Kromster Да, это можно использовать НЕ только как туториал для юнити, а и шире. Но код используется заточенный именно под юнити. Скриншоты/настройки/линки на документацию используются юнитовские. Если вопрос касается `Array` -- то с него же не убирается метка `C#` только потому, что ответ будет подобный и для других языков. Думаю, что метки можно, все таки, оставлять.

Comment: Метка относится к вопросу, а не к ответу. Но вы правы, в данном случае все не так просто.

Comment: Нужно обязательно почитать, про силу трения это мощно)

Answer (score 65, accepted):

## Перед прочтением важно знать

0. В любом случае на персонаж должен быть навешан RigidBody - скрипт отвечающий за физику персонажа (силу притяжения, силу трения и т.д.)
1. Хоть я здесь и разбираю в т.ч. нефизическое движение, я настоятельно рекомендую использовать ФИЗИЧЕСКОЕ движение. И переходить на нефизическое только в исключительных ситуациях.
2. В коде **не должно быть прямой привязки к кнопкам**. Должна быть привязка к параметрам  [Input Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-InputManager.html) . Которые можно найти в: `Edit -> Project Settings -> Input`. Нужно принять это как аксиому и не отходить, несмотря, на то что вы там нагуглите.
3. Я буду использовать здесь 2 термина: "телепортация" и "плавное движение". В моем понимании:

- Плавное движение - перерасчет позиции обьекта в рамках физики или паралельно физике на вызове `FixedUpdate()`.
- Телепортация - перерасчет позиции обьекта на промежутке времени большем чем `fixedDeltaTime`.

> Есть люди у которых мнение отличается.

- Плавное движение - исключительно физическое движение
- Телепортация - изменение позиции вручную или использование `.Translate()` метода.
- **UPD: и кстате они правы - но мне влом править весь текст - Translate внутри использует телепортацию на каждом кадре** https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs

> **Учтите, что все что написано ниже упирается в верхние значения терминов, а не эти.**

---

Двигать обьекты в игровых движках можно следующими способами:

- используя физический движок *(движение обусловленное физической моделью игрового движка)*
- движение  НЕфизическое. Неправильный подход -- подход телепортации на каждом кадре. (в `Update()` )
- движение НЕфизическое. Правильный подход -- плавное передвижение обьекта между кадрами (паралельно каждому просчету физики) (все равно желательно не использовать)
- Движение реализуемое через CharacterController (здесь пока что не рассматривается т.к. новички в его сторону вообще не смотрят, может, позже распишу)

> На практике метод передвижения подбирается под конкретного персонажа[персонажа -- не буквально. Это может быть и автомобиль]. В одном случае лучше будет физическое перемещение. В другом -- нефизическое. В третьем случае будет лучше всего CharacterController. Понимание что лучше в каком случае прийдет с практикой.

**Новички очень часто использую телепортацию на каждом кадре, что есть критически неправильным подходом**. Потом на SO появляются кучи клонов вопросов вроде "почему персонажа дергает возле стены?" или "почему он проходит сквозь стену?" или "почему пуля не всегда наносит урон?" и подобные.

Нужно запомнить всего одно правило: **Двигать/поворачивать через присвоение `transform.position`/`transform.rotation` нельзя. Это порождает проблемы.** В любом случае это вам вылезет боком.

Все для чего нужно это -- телепортация в другое место обьекта, но никак не его движения.

## Пример правильной реализации движения:

( на примере обьекта-шара )

```
using UnityEngine;

//эта строчка гарантирует что наш скрипт не завалится 
//ести на плеере будет отсутствовать компонент Rigidbody
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 10f;
    public float JumpForce = 300f;

    //что бы эта переменная работала добавьте тэг "Ground" на вашу поверхность земли
    private bool _isGrounded;
    private Rigidbody _rb;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // обратите внимание что все действия с физикой 
    // необходимо обрабатывать в FixedUpdate, а не в Update
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovementLogic();
        JumpLogic();
    }

    private void MovementLogic()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        _rb.AddForce(movement * Speed);
    }

    private void JumpLogic()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Jump") > 0)
        {
            if (_isGrounded)
            {
                _rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpForce);

                // Обратите внимание что я делаю на основе Vector3.up 
                // а не на основе transform.up. Если персонаж упал или 
                // если персонаж -- шар, то его личный "верх" может 
                // любое направление. Влево, вправо, вниз...
                // Но нам нужен скачек только в абсолютный вверх, 
                // потому и Vector3.up
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, true);
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, false);
    }

    private void IsGroundedUpate(Collision collision, bool value)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == ("Ground"))
        {
            _isGrounded = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Основой для этого скрипта послужил код взятый из: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-player

> Обратите внимание что за основу взят код из официальной документации/туториалов по юнити. Если есть несколько источников информации по какому-то мелкому но часто задаваемому вопросу (например движение персонажа ) -- выбирайте официальную документацию! Там точно фигни не посоветуют,

...

> в отличии от пестрящих дичью форумов, в т.ч. сервисе вопросов/ответов от юнити. Там в таких темах слишком часто пишут ответы те люди, которые понятия не имеют о правильном подходе.

Пример результата:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Связанные с темой понятия:

Есть `Update()` -- этот метод вызывается на каждой прорисовке кадра. `Time.DeltaTime`- это расчетное время между прорисовкой двух кадров. Если FPS проседает на компьютере, то этот параметр возрастает пропорционально проседанию.

Есть `FixedUpdate()` - это метод который вызывается при перепросчете физики. `Time.FixedDeltaTime`, как вы уже догадались, это время между вызовами `FixedUpdate()`. Оно может изменятся вручную через настройки, но упирается в физические возможности машины на которой игра будет запущена.

Если обьект не обладает физическими свойствами (не имеет RigidBody) эти параметры и методы можно использовать для НЕфизического передвижения.

Например поворот камеры.

Или крутящийся куб на небосводе.

Или движущийся изображение поезда где-то далеко, к которому нельзя подойти близко. Физика такому обьекту просто ни к чему -- это просто лишняя трата ресурсов

> но, даже, в этом случае предпочтительно использовать [Transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html) , но про это позже

Мы не получим дергающуюся картинку при проседании кадров если сделаем НЕФИЗИЧЕСКОЕ движение правильно:

> ВАЖНО: !!!ПРИМЕР ВРЕДНОГО КОДА!!!! Не делайте так!

```
// код для Update()
transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.DeltaTime;

// или же код для FixedUpdate()
transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.FixedDeltaTime;
```

мы присваиваем в новую позицию:

1. старую позицию
2. направление движения
3. скорость передвижения умноженную на `Time.deltaTime`.

Поэтому, даже, если, у нас было 60 кадров и случилось проседание до 10 кадров -- скорость вращения/движения обьекта не будет изменятся. Ведь, мы ее учитываем вместе с проседанием кадров.

---

## Про физические свойства движения.

Допустим мы двигаем обьект через `rb.Velocity` или через `AddForce()`, то это физическое движение обьекта. То есть она может изменятся во времени сама под действием неких физических законов. Например, мы задумали сделать прыжок персонажа:

```
if (IsGrounded && Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 100, 0);
}
```

мы разово задаем вектор скачка. Только 1 долю секунды. Но он будет изменятся во времени автоматически равномерно уменьшаясь под силой тяжения. Пока не станет нулевым (верхняя точка прыжка), а потом не пойдет в минус по `Y` (падение), а потом не упадет на землю и не отскочит от нее (снова плюс по `Y`) и так до полной остановки физической скорости обьекта на земле.

Допустим, мы двигаем изменением `transform.Positon` нашего плеера вперед по нажатию клавиши "пробел". В какой-то момент мы перестаем нажимать кнопку -- движение резко остановится и замрет. Это потому, что наше движение НЕ является физическим. Допустим мы подойдем к стенке и попробуем пройти на нее. Т.к. мы занимаемся телепортацией обьекта, то наш персонаж сначала дойдет до стенки, а потом телепортируется ВНУТРЬ нее, после чего `Collider` ее вытолкнет из себя. Как глубоко телепортируется внутрь зависит лишь от того, на какое расстояние мы телепортируем нашего персонажа за кадр. То есть это **"Bad Practice"** так реализовать перемещение персонажа.

Но в то же время есть и допустимое не-физическое перемещение. Это использование  метода `Transform.Translate()`. Это (вроде как) тоже телепортация, но с попыткой плавного нефизического перемещения обьекта. Но использование этого метода не освобождает нас от использования deltaTime/fixedDeltaTime, как в примере [оф.документации](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html).

( Снова таки - если на вашем обьекте есть RigidBody - наверняка нужно использовать физическое перемещение все равно! )

Если девайс с игрой сильно загружен, вызов методов  `Update()`/`FixedUpdate()` тоже может просесть в скорости. И если в физике это учтено и без нас, то сейчас мы делаем НЕ физическое движение и именно по-этому это нужно учитывать добавлением даного множителя.

Но и без использования даного множителя у нас не появится проблем с провалами сквозь стены. Это просто фикс скорости.

---

## Пример простой но хорошей НЕФИЗИЧЕСКОЙ реализации кода движения на примере персонажа.

Если в прошлом примере мы двигали шар, то было допустимо его толкать используя физ.модель. То есть мы использовали `AddForce()` для этих целей.

Допустим у нас персонаж -- человек, а не шар. Давай создадим вместо человека его подобие -- высокий куб 0.8х1.8х0.3 и попробуем нацепить на него наш скрипт движения шара. Выйдет следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть когда мы пытаемся подвигать, наш персонаж падает (мы ж его толкаем, логично!). Когда он упал -- он не может двигатся из-за силы трения. Зато мы можем двигать его в прыжке. :)

Давайте актуализируем этот код под даного персонажа. Мы заменим физический толчек обьекта на не-физическое, но **ПЛАВНОЕ** перемещение обьекта в пространстве:

```
using UnityEngine;

//эта строчка гарантирует что наш скрипт не завалится ести на плеере будет отсутствовать компонент Rigidbody
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // т.к. логика движения изменилась мы выставили меньшее и более стандартное значение
    public float Speed = 5f;

    public float JumpForce = 300f;

    //что бы эта переменная работала добавьте тэг "Ground" на вашу поверхность земли
    private bool _isGrounded;
    private Rigidbody _rb;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        //обратите внимание что все действия с физикой 
        //желательно делать в FixedUpdate, а не в Update
        JumpLogic();

        // в даном случае допустимо использовать это здесь, но можно и в Update.
        // но раз уж вызываем здесь, то 
        // двигать будем используя множитель fixedDeltaTimе 
        MovementLogic();
    }
    
    private void MovementLogic()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        // что бы скорость была стабильной в любом случае
        // и учитывая что мы вызываем из FixedUpdate мы умножаем на fixedDeltaTimе
        transform.Translate(movement * Speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }

    private void JumpLogic()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Jump") > 0)
        {
            if (_isGrounded)
            {
                // Обратите внимание что я делаю на основе Vector3.up а не на основе transform.up
                // если наш персонаж это шар -- его up может быть в том числе и вниз и влево и вправо. 
                // Но нам нужен скачек только вверх! Потому и Vector3.up
                _rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpForce);
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, true);
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, false);
    }

    private void IsGroundedUpate(Collision collision, bool value)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == ("Ground"))
        {
            _isGrounded = value;
        }
    }
}
```

С этим кодом мы получим такой результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С такой реализацией у нас не будет проблем вроде скачков скорости на проседании или повышении количества FPS, проваливаний, дерганости, прохождения сквозь стены или других неожиданностей.

Теперь мы можем занятся украшательствами -- например повороты тела. Довольно приятно реализованы повороты вот здесь:
[Как сделать управление, как в игре "Overcooked"?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/931703/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%83%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b5-overcooked)

Так же можно добавить анимацию бега на нашего персонажа (ну если бы это был не куб).

---

## Но как же реализация на физике?

Да, можно подобное реализовать и на физике.

Наша прошлая версия скрипта имела несколько недостатков. А именно:

- нужно было вручную отмечать каждый из предметов от которого мы можем прыгать. То есть добавив ящик на пол, нам нужно еще и его отметить тэгом Ground.
- если поставить кучу ящиков вертикально, присвоить каждому из них тэг "Ground", то просто подойдя к вертикальной стене из ящиков мы сможем взлететь вверх). То есть нам не важно к чему мы дотрагиваемся -- к полу или к стене -- оно давало нам возможность прыгать.
- наше движение все так же было НЕ физическим. То есть если мы начнем двигать игрока влево-вправо то он будет резко останавливатся а потом резко двигатся в противоположную сторону. В живом мире так не бывает.

> Вспомните уроки физкультуры, когда нужно было пробежать 30 метров вперед, взять палочку, пробежать 30 метров назад, положить палочку и еще раз 30 метров в другую сторону... Что случалось с бегуном в этот момент если посмотреть сбоку? Сначала скорость растет, потом достигает пика, а потом торможение, взятие палочки, бег в другую сторону -- снова возрастание скорости. Никаких резких скачков. Этого можно добится именно передвижением при помощи физики.

Давайте поместим на наш куб `CapsuleCollider` (минимальное торможение из-за силы трения) и заблочим в `rigidBody` `rotateX` и `rotateZ`(что б наш персонаж не падал на бок).

А потом нацепим на него вот этот скрипт:

```
using UnityEngine;

//эти строчки гарантирют что наш скрипт не завалится если на плеере будет отсутствовать нужные компоненты
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(CapsuleCollider))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 0.3f;
    public float JumpForce = 1f;

    //даем возможность выбрать тэг пола.
    //так же убедитесь что ваш Player сам не относится к даному слою. 

    //!!!!Нацепите на него нестандартный Layer, например Player!!!!
    public LayerMask GroundLayer = 1; // 1 == "Default"

    private Rigidbody _rb;
    private CapsuleCollider _collider; // теперь прийдется использовать CapsuleCollider
    //и удалите бокс коллайдер если он есть

    private bool _isGrounded
    {
        get {
            var bottomCenterPoint = new Vector3(_collider.bounds.center.x, _collider.bounds.min.y, _collider.bounds.center.z);

            //создаем невидимую физическую капсулу и проверяем не пересекает ли она обьект который относится к полу

            //_collider.bounds.size.x / 2 * 0.9f -- эта странная конструкция берет радиус обьекта.
            // был бы обязательно сферой -- брался бы радиус напрямую, а так пишем по-универсальнее

            return Physics.CheckCapsule(_collider.bounds.center, bottomCenterPoint, _collider.bounds.size.x / 2 * 0.9f, GroundLayer);
            // если можно будет прыгать в воздухе, то нужно будет изменить коэфициент 0.9 на меньший.
        }
    }

    private Vector3 _movementVector
    {
        get
        {
            var horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            var vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

            return new Vector3(horizontal, 0.0f, vertical);
        }
    }

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        _collider = GetComponent<CapsuleCollider>();

        //т.к. нам не нужно что бы персонаж мог падать сам по-себе без нашего на то указания.
        //то нужно заблочить поворот по осях X и Z
        _rb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationX | RigidbodyConstraints.FreezeRotationZ;

        //  Защита от дурака
        if (GroundLayer == gameObject.layer)
            Debug.LogError("Player SortingLayer must be different from Ground SourtingLayer!");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        JumpLogic();
        MoveLogic();
    }

    private void MoveLogic()
    {
        // т.к. мы сейчас решили использовать физическое движение снова,
        // мы убрали и множитель Time.fixedDeltaTime
        _rb.AddForce(_movementVector * Speed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }

    private void JumpLogic()
    {
        if (_isGrounded && (Input.GetAxis("Jump") > 0))
        {
            _rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вы видите эту плавность, как будто человек бежит, останавливается, бежит в другую сторону? Красота!

А теперь вернитесь к прошлой гифке и присмотритесь... Движение совсем не такое :) Там как буд-то рукой двигают шахматную фигуру по доске.

Ну и описанные выше баги поведения были пофикшены с такой реализацией.

Можно добавить еще физический материал нашему персонажу и откоректировать его поведение.

Вообще улучшать реализацию можно до бесконечности. Но, думаю, основные проблемы **СПОСОБОВ ПЕРЕДВИЖЕНИЯ** с которыми вы столкнетесь, я затронул :)

> **Оптимально использовать именно передвижение на базе физики.**

> **Пытайтесь использовать исключительно физическое передвижение.**

---

## Реализация нестандартной физики движений.

Одним из моих любимейших примеров нестандартной физики движения является игра **Ori and the Blind Forest**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKLxJTvaVy0

Такое перемещение/такие прыжки невозможно сделать на основе стандартной физики. Вероятнее всего, это делалось через **физическое перемещение** + костыли для получения нужных эфектов которые противоречат стандартной физике.

Сначала разрабатываются концепты движения. Они делаются в любом видеоредакторе с примитивными фигурами. Вот пример (если станет недоступным искать можно по [Ori and the blind forest Enemy Concepts](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Ori%20and%20the%20blind%20forest%20Enemy%20Concepts&safe=off&client=opera&hs=Omc&sxsrf=ACYBGNSZpa_4vZHjWJkomY3GrfH_nK_oUQ:1575802400570&source=lnms&tbm=vid&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjIw8my8aXmAhUGmYsKHdj3AUYQ_AUoAnoECCkQBA&biw=1240&bih=680&dpr=2) ) :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A8cV-oJfsjk

Обратите внимание на то, то здесь прорисовано не только перемещение обьекта, но и его вытягивания/сжатия. Изменения формы во время любого взаимодействия с внешним миром. В т.ч. выстрелы так же влияют на форму. А так же что указываются радиусы опознавания главного героя каждым отдельным врагом.

Костыли для каждого персонажа/врага свои собственные. Это делается что бы каждый из них обладал своей уникальной физикой. Сделать это на общей физике навряд ли возможно.

---

## Движение реализовано "правильно" но предмет все равно пролетает сквозь стену

ДАЖЕ если вы реализовали физическое передвижение вашего персонажа, все равно может случится такое, что просчет CollisionDetect может проходить с ошибками. Такое бывает.

Для таких случаев есть настройки отвечающие за обработку CollisionDetect в настройках самого RigidBody.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Желательно такого не делать т.к. это негативно сказывается на производительности. Чем на большем количестве обьектов вы меняете эти настройки, тем более вероятно что вы делаете какую-то дичь, которую делать совсем не нужно. Считайте это спасательным кругом, а не панацеей.** А если вы так будете делать, то рано или поздно вы прийдете на SO с вопросом почему игра тормозит, вас попросят показать код и ничего не найдут просто потому, что проблема тормозов не в коде. И намучаетесь вы с оптимизациями ой как сильно.

Так делать - не является ошибкой(!). Но чем меньше вы так будете делать - тем лучше. Подходите к изменению этих настроек с умом!

---

Информация для самостоятельного изучения:

- [NavMesh](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html)
- [Character Controller](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CharacterController.html)
- В вот этом видео (с которым я **НАСТОЯТЕЛЬНО** советую ознакомится)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=puPjNRJMmOc рассказывается уже немного другие штуки. Если на примерах в которых я выше описывал наш персонаж двигался исключительно по ровной поверхности (т.е. могут возникнуть сложности на террейне или же на наклонных ровных проскостях), то здесь уже описано как персонаж должен двигаться по неровных поверхностях.

Comment: Проблема в том, что моя реализация управления по типу Overcooked реализована как раз через transform, я не то, что бы много раз с этим сталкивался, но у меня есть некие сомнения, можно ли крутить физический объект через transform, хотя могу ошибаться :)

Comment: @RiotBr3aker можно, если это через `Translate()` (а у тебя там использован именно он). Т.к. он не телепортирует обьект, а именно что двигает в пространстве (хоть и не физикой) и убирает те негативные проблемы, с которыми сталкиваются постоянно новички :)

Comment: Так я про поворот, а не про `Translate`.

Comment: Подход ровно тот же -- использовать `transform.Rotate()` для такого случая вместо присвоения quaterion-a поворота в `transform.rotation`/`transform.localRotation`. То есть все по канону у тебя))

Comment: Интересная особенность, буду знать.

Comment: Прочитал разговор титанов. Сохраню в закладки и избранное, именно благодаря таким как Вы новички много нового узнают.

Comment: @PinPin позже я еще добавлю правильную реализацию движения на физике для сложных персонажей :) там тоже будет интересно)

Comment: @Andrew ок, жду, я всё смотрю, не пропущу

Comment: @Andrew "Движение реализовано "правильно" но предмет все равно пролетает сквозь стену" Как сделать все плавнее?  А то если едешь в камень, то дергается все сильно

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов я не умею гадать на кофейной гуще не видя кода. Я не знаю какие ошибки ты мог допустить там. Но основные ошибки и нюансы касающиеся реализации передвижения я перебрал в ответе выше. Начни с того что в принципе внимательно изучи написанное, перебери весь написанный код и разберись почему этот код писался именно так. Благо, я оставил в нем очень много коментариев.

Comment: И все же про `Translate` тут написана откровенная неправда, он все так же телепортирует объекты для физики: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs

Comment: @Andrew код был в моем вопросе, там pastebin, сможете найти?