# Не точно ставятся объекты в unity

Tags: unity3d, mesh

Сделал функцию, когда нажимаешь на кнопку вверху слева появляется объект, он двигается вслед за курсором, нажимаешь ЛКМ и он ставится. Вопрос в том, что некоторые объекты ставятся не ровно на пол, какие-то ровно, какие-то наполовину в земле, а некоторые в воздухе.

На земле стоит только MeshCollider, на объектах стоит BoxCollider и Rigtbody с отключенной гравитацией и включенной кинематикой.На объекты ставил BoxСollider - результата не дало. В чем может быть проблема?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Второй вопрос тоже про объект. При передвижении объекта на карте, если перемещаешь объект рядом с другим, возникают лаги и зависания движения, в чем может проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Скриншот передвижения объекта

Comment: по поводу второго вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа-почему-мой-персонаж-дергается-д

Comment: по поводу первого- слишком мало информации. Может ты криво расположил бокс коллайдер, может как-то криво реализовал передвижение, может у тебя какие-то дикие настройки физики... Здесь тебе точно никто не подскажет по поданной информации.

Comment: В том то и дело что бокс коллайдер поставил ровно, но сам обьект висит в воздухе

Comment: повторюсь: причин может быть миллион, а поданной информации слишком мало что бы ответить не тыкая пальцем в небо. Сидеть и тыкать пальцем в небо вряд ли кто будет.

Comment: Какую информацию предоставить тогда?

Comment: какие компоненты висят на обьектах, настройки гравитации, скрипты передвижения, скриншоты на которых видно как именно криво приземляются обьекты но так что бы было видно их коллайдеры. -- Все что только может влиять на проблему.

Comment: Добавил, скриншоты земли,объекта, и как он стоит в игре

Comment: а теперь не хватает скрипта, которым вы объекты расставляете

Comment: Выложил скриншот

Answer (score 0, accepted):

у тебя нету коллайдера на плейне. Оно проваливается сквозь плейн и становится ровно. Просто на Terrain, а не на плейн.