# Почему Unity игнорирует BoxCollider2D и CircleCollder2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

[image: Видна часть ноги робота под турелью(слева от центра, робот передвигается на некоторое расстояние через равные промежутки времени)]

В скриптах, которые висят на этих объектах нет элементов влияющих на  `BoxCollider2D` и `CircleCollider2D`, перемещение осуществляется с помощью `transform.position += x;`, где x некоторый `Vector3` элемент (поскольку для подобного рода игры адекватные способы перемещения через `veliocity` или `AddForce()` не придумал). Почему Турель с `CircleCollidet2D` на `TurrelAim` игнорирует коллизию с `BoxCollider2D` на `Pawuk`?

Comment: используйте медленное решение - поставьте в настройках rigidbody collision detection - continous dymanic

Comment: Потому что `transform.position += x;` - это в прямом смысле слова телепортация. Физика ну просто не может отследить такое. Максимум, что **может** помочь - совет комментарием выше.

Comment: Я использую `transform.position += x`через `FixedUpdate`так что, насколько я знаю, все должно работать нормально

Comment: "насколько я знаю" - ссылки, пожалуйста, или это лишь ваши догадки? `Trasform` не имеет вообще ничего общего с физикой, где бы он не менялся, это **не физическая величина**.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа-почему-мой-персонаж-дергается-д

Answer (score 2):

Давайте рассуждать логически. Как, по-вашему, физический движок поймёт, с чем столкнулся объект, если вы используете `transform.position += x;`?

Скажем:

```
                        стена 1              стена 2
                          |                    |
старая_позиция_объекта    |                    |           новая_позиция_объекта
                          |                    |
```

Если вы явно поменяли координаты, то что Unity должен решить? Столкнулись ли вы со стеной 1? Или со стеной 2? Или с обеими? Или ни с одной?

Если вы хотите, чтоб коллизии нормально обрабатывались, то меняйте позицию объектов, прикладывая силу, e.g. `rigidbody.velocity = x` или `rigidbody.MovePosition`.