# Проблема с двойным прыжком на Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

у меня есть проблема с игрой на Unity. Я решил сделать небольшую игру типа платформера, есть проблема с прыжком, если очень много раз нажимать на кнопку прыжка он просто просто улетает вверх(прыгает по воздуху), нужно это как-то исправить.

Вот сам код.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Her : MonoBehaviour

{



    Rigidbody2D rb;
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }



    void Update()
    {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                {
                    jump();
                }

    }
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * 12f, rb.velocity.y);
        }


    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D p)
    {
        if (p.gameObject.tag == "ReloadLevel")
        {
            RestartLevel();
        }
    }


        void RestartLevel()
    {
        Application.LoadLevel(Application.loadedLevel);
    }

        void jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * 12f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: добавтье провекрку коллизии с прверзерстью, как условие для добавления силы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В комментарии написали, что можно добавить проверку коллизии с поверхностью (стоит ли персонаж на земле), но проблема иногда все равно будет заметна, особенно если персонаж будет бегать и прыгать на неровной поверхности. Пусть обьект, который будет прыгать будет называтся Person, а вспомогательный обьект будет называтся JumpTracker. Для того, что бы решить проблему нужно добавить обьект JumpTracker и расположить его прямо на грани, где будет Person встречатся с землей. Обьект JumpTracker нужно в 2-4 раза меньше, чем обьект Person (высота y, ширина x, глубина z), также добавить на него коллайдер и поставить галочку isTrigger. Нужно создать скрипт JumpTrackerScript, где будет метод OnTriggerStay(collider collider) (или как там) и if (collider.gameObject.transform.tag == "ground") { isGround = true; } Как-то так, возможно много неточностей с моей стороны.

Answer (score 2):

Если заглянуть в этот вопрос: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4)

можно увидеть интересную реализацию проверки IsGrounded через

```
private bool _isGrounded
{
    get {
        var bottomCenterPoint = new Vector3(_collider.bounds.center.x, _collider.bounds.min.y, _collider.bounds.center.z);

        //создаем невидимую физическую капсулу и проверяем не пересекает ли она обьект который относится к полу

        //_collider.bounds.size.x / 2 * 0.9f -- эта странная конструкция берет радиус обьекта.
        // был бы обязательно сферой -- брался бы радиус напрямую, а так пишем по-универсальнее

        return Physics.CheckCapsule(_collider.bounds.center, bottomCenterPoint, _collider.bounds.size.x / 2 * 0.9f, GroundLayer);
        // если можно будет прыгать в воздухе, то нужно будет изменить коэфициент 0.9 на меньший.
    }
}
```

если нужен 2йной прыжок нужно сделать так же, только с задержкой между прыжками во времени. Что бы нельзя было зажать кнопку прыжка и взлетать. То есть проверяем на isGrounded, делаем прыжок если все ок и засекаем время до следующего возможного прыжка. А после второго прыжка делать возможным только снова по IsGrounded.

Так же нужно реализовать счетчик прыжков что бы нельзя было всегда летать. То есть 2 прыжка, а потом уже не прыгать пока персонаж не попадет снова на землю.