# Хочу двойной прыжок

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытался сделать двойной прыжок, ну или одиночный еще точно не знаю, а у меня персонаж летает, ну то есть прыгает сколько хочет. У меня уже стоит под ним платформа и он считывает землю, вроде бы, но он все равно летает

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
public float speed = 12; // Выводим в меню где можно все поменять, кликнув на персонажа
public float jumpheight = 12;

private int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue;

private bool isGrounded;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float checkRadius;
public LayerMask WhatisGround;


Rigidbody2D rb;
Animator anim; //сокращаем название

void Start()
{
    extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); // Включили боксколайдер 
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); // Включили анимацию
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, WhatisGround);
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, rb.velocity.y); //Функция бега
}
void Update() {

    if (isGrounded = true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0)
    {
        Jump();
        extraJumps--;
    }else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && isGrounded == true)
    {
        Jump();
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") == 0) {
        anim.SetInteger ("popka", 1);
    } else {
        Flip();
        anim.SetInteger("popka", 2);
    }
}
void Flip()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 200, 0);

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler (0, 0, 0);
}
void Jump()
{ rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpheight, ForceMode2D.Impulse); }

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с двойным прыжком на Unity](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/954002/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b9%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc-%d0%bf%d1%80%d1%8b%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-unity)

Comment: Не стоит заставлять участников SO угадывать Ваши мысли. Будьте конкретны и понятны в своем вопросе. Попробуйте переформулировать свой вопрос и включить минимум кода, относящийся непосредственно к вопросу, но не меньше, чем надо для понимания. А то у Вас как в "Чародеях" - "Хочу Аленушку!"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты пытаешься присвоить внутри условия if `if (isGrounded = true) {}`.
if нужно получить bool значение и используется операция сравнения "==", а не присвоения "=", но isGrounded сам по себе является bool `if (isGrounded) {}`.
Функция Flip странная, ты не флипаешь, а вертишь.

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody2D))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(Animator))]

public class Runner : MonoBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _groundLayer;
    [SerializeField] private Transform _groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private float _checkRadius = 1;
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 12;
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpForce = 12;
    [SerializeField] private int _baseJump = 2;
    [SerializeField] private float _fallVelocityMark = -1;
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;
    private const string _animName = "popka";
    private Rigidbody2D _body;
    private Animator _anim;
    private Transform _transform;
    private int _jumps;
    private bool _isGrounded;

    private void Awake () {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        _anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        _transform = transform;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(_jumpKey)) 
            Jump();
        if (_isGrounded)
            Move();
        else if (_body.velocity.y < 0 && CheckGroundCollide())
            Landing();
    }

    private void Move () {
        float Vector = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        _body.velocity = new Vector2(Vector*_speed, _body.velocity.y);
        if (Vector == 0)
            _anim.SetInteger(_animName, 1);
        else {
            _anim.SetInteger(_animName, 2);
            Flip(Vector);
        }
        if (_body.velocity.y < _fallVelocityMark)
            Fall();
    }

    private void Flip (float vector) {
        _transform.localScale = vector < 0 ? Vector3.one : new Vector3(-1, 1, 1);
    }

    private void Jump () {
        if (_jumps > 0) {
            _isGrounded = false;
            _jumps--;
            _body.AddForce(transform.up*_jumpForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
    }

    private void Landing () {
        _isGrounded = true;
        _jumps = _baseJump;
    }

    private void Fall () {
        _isGrounded = false;
        _jumps -= 1;
    }

    private bool CheckGroundCollide () {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(_groundCheck.position, _checkRadius, _groundLayer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Код странный, но рабочий, единственно не хватает 1 условия, а именно нужно обратиться к колайдерам, а затем для прыжка обозначить количество колайдеров, при которых будет доступен прыжок. Но можно было прописать это все более читаемо и компактно.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
public float speed = 12; // Выводим в меню где можно все поменять, кликнув 
на персонажа
public float jumpheight = 12;

private int extraJumps;
public int extraJumpsValue;

private bool isGrounded;
public Transform groundCheck;
public float checkRadius;
public LayerMask WhatisGround;


Rigidbody2D rb;
Animator anim; //сокращаем название

void Start()
{
    extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); // Включили боксколайдер 
    anim = GetComponent<Animator>(); // Включили анимацию
}
void FixedUpdate()
{
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, 
WhatisGround);
    Collider2D[] colliders = 
Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(groundCheck.position, 0.5f);
    isGrounded = colliders.Length > 1;
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed, 
rb.velocity.y); //Функция бега
}
void Update()
{

    if (isGrounded == true)
    {
        extraJumps = extraJumpsValue;
    }

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps > 0)
    {
        Jump();
        extraJumps--;
    }
    else if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && extraJumps == 0 && 
 isGrounded == true)
    {
        Jump();
    }

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") == 0)
    {
        anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
    }
    else
    {
        Flip();
        anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
    }
}
void Flip()
{
    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0)
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 200, 0);

    if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0)
        transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, 0);
}
void Jump()
{ rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpheight, ForceMode2D.Impulse); }

}
```