# Двойной прыжок и прыжок в зависимости от долготы зажатия кнопки

Tags: unity3d

Я пытаюсь создать игру с двойным прыжком + прыжок от времени нажатия кнопки. Двойной прыжок должен сработать, когда персонаж входит в триггер другого игрового объекта. Как в игре "Geometry Dash". У меня с этим возникли трудности, сам двойной прыжок не работает.

Вот код другого игрового объекта:

```
public class CubeController : MyCharacterController
{
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Player")
        {
            ExtraJump++;
        }
    }
}
```

Вот код прыжка:

```
    int extraJump = 0;
    int defaultExtraJump = 1;
    protected int ExtraJump { get => extraJump; set => extraJump = value; }
float littleJumpForce = 20;
    float jumpForce = 60;
    float maxJumpTime=0.1f;
    float defaultMaxJumpTime = 0.1f;

public void CheckGround()
    {
        isGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.transform.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
    }
 void Start()
    {
        maxJumpTime = defaultMaxJumpTime;
        extraJump = defaultExtraJump;
    }
  private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Jump();
        CheckGround();
    }
public void Jump()
    {
        if (isGround)
        {
            maxJumpTime = defaultMaxJumpTime;
            extraJump = defaultExtraJump;
        }
    if (extraJump > 0)
    {
        if (isGround && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, littleJumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            maxJumpTime = defaultMaxJumpTime;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && maxJumpTime >= 0)
        {
            maxJumpTime -= Time.deltaTime * 4;
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow) && !isGround)
        {
            maxJumpTime = -1;
            extraJump--;
        }
    }else if (extraJump == 0 && !isGround)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, littleJumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            maxJumpTime = defaultMaxJumpTime;
        }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow) && maxJumpTime >= 0)
        {
            maxJumpTime -= Time.deltaTime* 4;
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(0, jumpForce), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.UpArrow) && !isGround)
        {
            maxJumpTime = -1;
            extraJump--;
        }
    }
    animator.SetBool("isGround", false);
}
```

У меня очень мало опыта в Юнити(((
Помогите кто-то пожалуйста.

Comment: Вот чё за фигня... этот код я вижу +/- каждый месяц, но если забить в поиск `isGround = Physics2D.OverlapCircle`, сейчас там только 3 результата, а должны быть десятки. В чем дело?

Comment: А что не так с Physics2D.OverlapCircle? И я не писала что я "учу юнити". И курс по С# я давно прошла:)

Comment: Перед тем как что-то писать, я обязательно ищу информацию, чтобы знать, что написано. А вы вместо того, чтобы рассказывать, где и что бестолково написано, лучше бы помогли, а не показывали насколько вы самый умный и умеете грубить.

Comment: Кода видишь один и то-же скопированный код не первый десяток раз с +/- одни-ми и теми-же вопросами от пользователей которые зашли с ним на стек в первый и последний раз... если это и грубость, то уровня святого ангела . Знай ты, что написано, не было бы и вопроса. Вот, когда я встретил этот код впервые и ещё не было рвотного рефлекса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1026383/%D0%A5%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B6%D0%BE%D0%BA/1026613

Comment: Мой код отличается от этого, потому что я добавила прыжок от времени нажатия кнопки. Я читала эту тему, но у меня не получилось сделать так же, поэтому я и создала свою тему.

Comment: Когда я пришел на этот сайт (это был месяцев 5 назад), я еще не совсем понимал, какого рода вопросы здесь следует задавать, какие данные указывать в вопросе и т.д. И именно @Yaroslav был первым, кто отвечал на мои вопросы и указывал мне на ошибки, которые я в них допускал (из правил сайта это было мне почему-то не понятно). Поэтому советую вам его прислушиваться, да и вообще людей, кто давно на сайте - они вряд ли чего плохого посоветуют. И мне ЛИЧНО в вопросе режет глаза фраза `У меня с этим возникли трудности.` Какого рода трудности? Ошибка, не прыгает 2-й раз, еще что-то?

Comment: Что могу сразу сказать:  в методе Jump условие `else if (extraJump == 0 && !isGround)`, но уже в следующей строке вы прoверяете `if (isGround && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow))`. Если код дойдет до этой строки, значит isGround = false (Первое условие-то прошло), значит второе условие гарантированно не пройдет, там же требуется isGround == true, не так ли? Хотя я ни черта не понял проблему, предполагаю, что она заключается в этом. Так как без этого условия (которое требует isGround = true), не сработает второе (т.к. в первом задаются начальные значения для второго) и следовательно третье

Comment: @МаксимФисман  Да, была не права не уточнила в чем проблема. Она заключается в том, что сам двойной прыжок не работает, именно его я пыталась добавить к моему прыжку в зависимости от долготы зажатия кнопки. Вы правы с isGround была ошибка, но к сожалению прыжок от этого работать не стал. Я изменила на чем я остановился. Я уже много чего перепробовала, но ничего не выходит.

Comment: С одной стороны я понимаю Yaroslav , но с другой стороны можно просто написать в коментариях "Я намекну - этот вопрос решается через дебаггер в таком-то методе" и не грубить. Да и, вобщемто, Владислава если была бы достаточно опытной(как утверждает), а не просто "окончила курс" и сама бы догадалась что это решается через дебаггер. Дебаггер это вообще святая святых при любой проблеме. :) Вобщем, оба стоят один второго. Помиритесь, поцелуйтесь в щечку и давайте вместе повышать свои скилы, ведь, этот ресурс именно для этого :)

Comment: Вас не смущает что вы отслеживаете столкновение с игроков в классе, который как я понял по названию является контролером персонажа?