# Вопрос по коллайдерам

Tags: unity3d

Как сделать так, чтобы в блок коллайдера вообще нельзя было даже на пару пикселей попасть? Коллайдеры настроены верно, но танк все равно на чуть-чуть, но заезжает в текстуры.

> Коллайдер выталкивает объект, но если целеноправленно жать кнопку
>   вперед, то модель заезжает в текстуры.

КАК сделать полностью жесткий коллайдер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В - Сделайте коллайдер чуть больше, у вас может быть либо у камня либо у танка, коллайдер не ровно по текстуре

Comment: Тогда в других ситуациях, модель убдет проезжая мимо задевать пустоту, где логика?

Comment: Написано же, что коллайдеры идеально сделаны под объект, просто этот объект не сразу выталкивает

Comment: @ЯрославСмирнов а как вы двигаете танк?

Comment: if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) || moveup)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * moveSpeedup * Time.deltaTime);

Comment: И скахал Andrew: здесь ты найдешь ответ на свой вопрос и будет все хорошо: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b4 И добавил: Правда, если не поленишся переписать управление)

Comment: Дубликат вопроса т.к. проблема банально созданная не коллайдером, а неправильной реализацией перемещения :)

Answer (score 2):

Столкновения между коллайдерами обсчитывает физический движок для него [`transform.Translate()`](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Runtime/Transform/ScriptBindings/Transform.bindings.cs) это телепортация.

Чтобы физика работала Вам необходимо добавлять силы, которые воздействуют на объект, толкая его в направлении движения.

```
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleMoveForward : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float thrust;
    public Rigidbody rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * thrust);
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание что обработка физики происходит не в методе `Update` а в методе `FixedUpdate`. Он в отличие от `Update` срабатывает в четко определенные моменты времени, а когда будет вызван `Update` зависит он некоторых факторов, которые сложно предсказать. Например он может вызываться очень редко или не вызываться вообще для свернутых или не активных окон. `Update` - для графики, `FixedUpdate`- для физики.

---

Есть грязный способ - поставить у rigidbody `collision detection` - `continous dynamic`, он порождает дополнительную нагрузку на процессор

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91464/discussion-on-answer-by-stranger-in-the-q---).

Comment: @ЮрийСПб огромное спасибо :)

Answer (score 2):

Я просто займусь критикой кода

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeedup;
    public float moveSpeeddown;
    public float rotateSpeed;
    public bool moveup;
    public bool movedown;
    public bool rotateleft;
    public bool rotateright;
    void Update()
    {
        if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) || moveup)
        {
            transform.Translate(Vector3.right * moveSpeedup * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow) || movedown)
        {
            transform.Translate(-Vector3.right * moveSpeeddown * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow) || rotateleft)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || rotateright)
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
}
```

## В следующий раз, пожалуста, вставляй код в сам вопрос SO, а не в левые сервисы.

1. Убери всю логику в стиле

   ```
    if ((Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow)) || moveup)
   ```

Это должно реализоватся через

```
 Input.GetAxis
```

весь список нужных команд ты найдешь в Edit -> Project Settings -> Input

2. У тебя много лишних переменных. Достаточно обойтись:

   ```
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float rotateSpeed;
   ```

остальные тебе не нужны.

Если тебе хочется что бы скорость была разной, можно или ввести коэфициэнтное соотношение скорости вперед или назад, или же добавить переменные как у тебя были. (за исключением неиспользуемых)

Если это движение вперед-назад то это значение берется с плюсом или минусом. С ротейтом - идентично.

1. Для даного случая оптимальным было бы решение движения через AddForce. **Танк должен плавно останавливатся, а не резко.**

Возможно, нужно будет донастроить физический материал танка что бы получилось то что нужно тебе лично (длинна скольжения при остановке).

2. Множитель `Time.deltaTime` при использовании Translate() - лишний. Но в даном контексте, вероятно, лучше будет вызывать его из FixedUpdate().

   Если же очень хочется что бы движение было нефизическим, но плавность, все же, была -- нужно ее эмулировать, например, через библиотеку LeanTween -- искать по ключевику SetEase.

   Но я, все же, советую, использовать перемещение через AddForce.
3. Как нежелательная альтернатива решения проблемы в самом вопросе - можно выставить Continius CollisionDetect в настройках RigitBody.

---

И в любом случае я настоятельно рекомендую перейти на физическое движение. [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/186752)