# Почему изменилась физика, при использовании Network Manager и др?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добавил Network Manager и прочее, для LAN игры - при столкновении с коллайдерами, танк начинает очень быстро вращаться.

**- При запрете вращения по Z**

Модель при столкновении не вращается, но и никак не реагирует.

[image: GIF 1]

Раньше, когда не было Network, модель прижималась к стене, в общем, задевая коллайдер - доворачивала корпус, ехала параллельно коллайдеру. (есть только фото)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*Как вернуть привычную физику?*

Comment: Движение реализовано **не** через `AddForce` или какой-нибудь `velocity`?

Comment: transform.Translate

Comment: @Andrew, :)))))

Comment: Вам вчера много раз сказали переписать все через физику, чтобы коллизии работали. Вы ничего не  переписали, теперь ничего не работает, чему вы удивляетесь?

Comment: Я не смогу написать "физическое движение", а в интернете ничего нет

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)