# Unity3d: персонаж перестает двигаться после непродолжительного бездействия (AFK)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Персонаж перестает двигаться после непродолжительного бездействия (AFK).
Всегда через какое-то время (около 3 минут) бездействия в игре, т.е когда уходишь в афк, то персонаж перестает двигаться. Он поворачивается в нужную сторону, анимация передвижения также присутствует, но персонаж стоит на месте.
Я обычно делаю ALT + TAB, занимаюсь своими делами и когда возвращаюсь к игре - персонаж еле двигается либо вообще не двигается.
Параметры rb.velocity остаются неизменными, тут всё ок, также как и input от джойстиков.
Двигаю персонажа в каждом кадре, вот код передвижения:

```
// rb - это Rigidbody
// joystick - джойстик
rb.velocity = new Vector3(joystick.Horizontal * movementSpeed, rb.velocity.y, 
joystick.Vertical * movementSpeed);
```

Ссылка на видео демонстрацию - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gCiXeuT90_Y

Comment: посмотрите, не получается ли такая ситуация, что персонаж немного "проваливается" в плоскость земли или террейна. Может быть просто collider персонажа заходит немного внутрь другого коллаидра и делает движение невозможным.

Comment: странно, так и происходит, но почему? ведь я отключил гравитацию и заблокировал перемещение по Y

Comment: вот скриншот - http://joxi.ru/Y2LyOwDS7qgdVA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Посмотрите, не получается ли такая ситуация, что персонаж немного "проваливается" в плоскость земли или террейна. Может быть просто collider персонажа заходит немного внутрь другого коллаидра и делает движение невозможным.

Причин на то может быть много, но для первого предположения, вы реализовали передвижение персонажа не совсем корректно. В документации по [Rigitbody.Velocity](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-velocity.html) написано, что изменение Velocity может приводить не реалистичному поведению физики и в большинстве случаев, не стоит менять значение этого свойства. Кроме того, не рекомендуют менять значение этого свойства на каждое обновление физики.

По конкретно вашему отрывку кода - вы меняете это свойство напрямую, а оно вычисляется по средствам воздействия различных сил на объект. Вполне возможно, что 
`rb.velocity.y` у вас имеет не нулевое значение, а какое-нибудь очень небольшое и со временем объект все-таки вростает в землю. Вы в свою очередь, каждое обновление физики не даете этому значению обнулиться. На вашем месте, я бы попробовать изменить движение на [Rigidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html), благо это не займет много времени.

Comment: попробую, спасибо, отпишусь как попробую

Comment: попробовал через Addforce, персонажа стало кидать в разные стороны, стал ходить боком и т.д.

Comment: просто некорректно реализовали, возможно. Подставить теже коэффициенты, что были при прямой установке velocity тут не подойдут

Comment: а как тогда можно реализовать?

Comment: Попробуйте посмотреть здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0

Comment: отличный топик! спасибо!