# Как двигать шар горизонтально по плоскости?

Tags: c#, unity3d

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]Скрипт должен двигать шар горизонтально по плоскости, а он только падает.

Что делать?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody rb;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


     void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3 (moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        rb.AddForce (movement);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а на поверхности есть коллайдер?

Comment: или что имеется в виду под "он только падает" ?Он проходит сквозь плоскость  или  лежит и не двигается от ваших нажатий ?

Comment: попробуйте ещё rb.velocity = movement;

Comment: Чтобы не падал, отключите ему гравитацию. Еще возможно вы слишком маленькую силу к нему прикладываете.

Comment: Если "он только падает" (на Ground), то добавили ли вы ваш скрипт PlayerController к объекту Player?

Comment: @Yaroslav я его прописал,сохранил.Система не ругалась.А когда рендерит ,то падает из воздуха вниз и не катится

Comment: @Yaroslav я его вручную перетаскивал даже из папки прямо на шар и ничего.Есть куда побольше инфы показать(сообщения)?

Comment: @ПавелЛюбимов а можете показать скрин с инспектора вашего Шара  и плоскости?  Думаю это сможет прояснить

Comment: @Andrey добрый день.Вот скрин

Comment: @ПавелЛюбимов плохой скрин. Шар на сцене не выделен в инспекторе.

Comment: @Andrew так я же выделил шар на сцене и раскрыл весь инспектор по шару

Comment: @Andrew скидываю еще скрин

Comment: Посмотри в вот єтой теме https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0/936027#936027 скрипты. Там были рабочие скрипты которые я вешал на шар и спокойно им двигал.

Comment: @Аndrew так а почему скрипт с Unity не сработал?! Делал де все по уроку. А дальше нужно будет ,видимо к каждому уроку искать скрипты раз уже на втором уроке он не работает?!

Comment: @Andrew а есть возможность куда-нить лично писать?! Или только тут?!

Comment: только тут________

Comment: @Andrew я же правильно понял,что самый первый скрипт в ссылке вашей вставляю и запускаю? А почему тогла в официальном сайте не работает?! Ьакое бывает?!

Comment: У меня нету обьяснения почему) Может работает код с оф.документации. А может и нет.