# Как вращать объект вокруг своей оси?/Unity3d

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть шар который я хочу вращать вокруг своей оси вперед .

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сам вопрос был бы очень легкий ,если бы не одно но.

Движение объекта:

```
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + (transform.forward * Time.deltaTime *speed));
```

Для того чтобы изменять направления персонажа я его поворачиваю т.е. мне нужно использовать `forward` для того , что персонаж мог не просто идти вперед по оси X,а и изменять направления и двигаться по нему вперед.Но как вы понимаете если я просто начну вращать его например вот так `transform.Rotate(Vector3.right *3)`,то и `forward` не будет работать корректно.

Поворот объекта :

```
     private Touch touch1;
    
        private Vector2 TouchPosition;
    
        private Quaternion rotationY;
    
        private float rotateSpeedModifier = 0.7f;

        void Update()
{
            if (Input.touchCount > 0)
                    {
                        touch1 = Input.GetTouch(0);
                        if (touch1.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
                        {
                            rotationY = Quaternion.Euler(
                                0f,
                                touch1.deltaPosition.x * rotateSpeedModifier,
                                0f);
                            transform.rotation = rotationY * transform.rotation;
                        }
                    }
    }
```

Единственным выходом я вижу как то поменять механику движения,но как?

//Поворот анимацией ,наверное,плохая идея.

Comment: Вы видели rollerBall example из базовых ассетов?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Нет,не смотрел.Я понял свою ошибку.Иду смотреть.

Comment: я мог наврать с названием, раньше, где то в 5 версии, его нужно было в маркете найти, от издателя unity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оптимальным путем будет использовать физическое движение, а не вращать + двигать вперед.

```
using UnityEngine;

//эта строчка гарантирует что наш скрипт не завалится 
//ести на плеере будет отсутствовать компонент Rigidbody
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]
public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float Speed = 10f;
    public float JumpForce = 300f;

    //что бы эта переменная работала добавьте тэг "Ground" на вашу поверхность земли
    private bool _isGrounded;
    private Rigidbody _rb;

    void Start()
    {
        _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // обратите внимание что все действия с физикой 
    // необходимо обрабатывать в FixedUpdate, а не в Update
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        MovementLogic();
        JumpLogic();
    }

    private void MovementLogic()
    {
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

        _rb.AddForce(movement * Speed);
    }

    private void JumpLogic()
    {
        if (Input.GetAxis("Jump") > 0)
        {
            if (_isGrounded)
            {
                _rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpForce);

                // Обратите внимание что я делаю на основе Vector3.up 
                // а не на основе transform.up. Если персонаж упал или 
                // если персонаж -- шар, то его личный "верх" может 
                // любое направление. Влево, вправо, вниз...
                // Но нам нужен скачек только в абсолютный вверх, 
                // потому и Vector3.up
            }
        }
    }

    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, true);
    }

    void OnCollisionExit(Collision collision)
    {
        IsGroundedUpate(collision, false);
    }

    private void IsGroundedUpate(Collision collision, bool value)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.tag == ("Ground"))
        {
            _isGrounded = value;
        }
    }
}
```

код взят с темы:
[Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

а там взят с документации юнити и доработан.

В твоем случае тебе нужно вырезать логику прыжка, а так же залочить обьект по высоте (y) при касании "земли", на сколько я понимаю.

---

Но если уж отвечать на сам поставленный вопрос: как вращать шар вокруг своей оси...

для этого нужно использовать просто Rotate. Но самое главное что нужно учесть, что бы pivot point был в центре обьекта. Т.к. вращаться обьект будет именно вокруг него.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю как использовать это код для моей игры.Насколько я знаю ,                                                                              
        float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");                                                       используется для клавиш,возможно,это можно юзать и для смартфона,но я не не знаю как.Кстати,важное дополнение ,которое я забыл упомянуть -персонаж всегда двигается вперед,мне нужно контролировать только его повороты для изменения направления движения.

Comment: главное что возьми из кода - способ движения. Управление можешь подставить из своего кода.

Answer (score 0):

А почему бы не использовать локальные координаты?

Код:

```cs
transform.Translate(speed, 0, 0, Space.Self);
```

`speed` - скорость объекта

Ну и в принципе указывать систему координат вообще не обязательно, потому-что по умолчанию и так стоит `Space.Self`.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]