# Не получается сделать плавный поворот угла, космического корабля

Tags: unity3d

без добавление кнопок управление кораблем все работало, т. е. угол поворота угла корабля был плавным при смещение на лево на право, но после добавление кнопок на сцену, и добавление `event trigger` и функций к нему `OnLeft`, `OnRight`, поворот угла корабля стал очень быстрым, как это исправить подскажите пожалуйста.

```
public float tilt =5f;
public float horizontal;
public float vertical;
 void Start()
    {
        
        player = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        currentHealth = maxHealth;
        healthbar.SetMaxHealth(maxHealth);
        

    }
void Update()
    {

       
        player.velocity = new Vector3(horizontal, vertical, 7f);

        var clampedPositionX = Mathf.Clamp(player.position.x, xmin, xmax);
        var clampedPositionY = Mathf.Clamp(player.position.y, ymin, ymax);
        player.position = new Vector3(clampedPositionX, clampedPositionY, player.position.z);
        
        player.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(vertical*tilt,0, horizontal * tilt);


    }
 public void Onleft()
    {
        horizontal = -7f;
    }
    public void OnRigth()
    {
        horizontal = 7f;
    }
    public void Up()
    {
        vertical = 7f;
    }
    public void Down()
    {
        vertical=-7f;
    }
    public void UpButtonHor()
    {
        
            
        horizontal = 0f;
    }
    public void UpButtonVer()
    {
        vertical = 0f;
    }
```

Comment: Может делать horizontal и vertical равными не 7 и -7, а, например, 4 и -4? В соответствующих методах. При повороте вы умножаете их на tilt, можно уменьшить переменную tilt

Comment: весьма советую к прочтению https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа/936027#936027 здесь можно найти ошибки допущенные у тебя в коде и исправить заодно и конркетно эту проблему и кучу других, которые пока что не возникли, но возникнут позже.

Comment: Например здесь будет изменятся скорость поворота корабля в зависимости от количества кадров в секунду)

Comment: Уменьшил vertical и horizontal, не помогло, просто уменьшился угол поворота, и все, когда без кнопок и без этих методов, т. е. в Update(), угол наклона при повороте влево вправо он плавный, но стоит только добавить кнопки, то все, не работает так как прежде,  вот в чем проблемма.