# Подскажите, как реализовать touch на Uniyty 3D?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android, move

Делаю игру на Unity 3D. Мне нужно, чтобы куб двигался по **оси Z** вверх, или вниз(до "бортов"), при таче в определенную область экрана, соответственно в верхнюю, либо нижнюю. Я пробовал это сделать, но при таче, функция вызывается несколько раз, я в откладке это видно, соответствено куб двигается на несколько позиций.
Подскажите, как это исправить, чтобы при таче куб двигался только на одну позицию?

З.Ы. Я делаю игру по типу *endless runner*, поэтому куб двигается с постоянной скоростью по **оси X**.

Также, могли бы подсказать, как придать плавности движению куба при по **оси Z**?

Спасибо.

[image: План движения куба]

[image: Отладка (Debug.Log)]

```
private void Update()
{
    CubePosUp_Z = transform.position.z - 0.7f;
    CubePosDown_Z = transform.position.z + 0.7f;
    if (Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.position.y > Screen.height / 2)
        {
            tempUp = 1;
            tempDown = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            tempUp = 0;
            tempDown = 1;
        }

        if (tempUp == 1 && tempDown == 0)
        {
            UpTran();
        }
        else if (tempUp == 0 && tempDown == 1)
        {
            DownTran();
        }
    }
}

void UpTran()
{
    Debug.Log("Up");

    if (CubePosUp_Z <= -1.4)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 0, Space.World);
    }
    else if (CubePosUp_Z > -1.4)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, -0.14f, Space.World);
    }
}
void DownTran()
{
    if (CubePosDown_Z >= 1.4)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 0, Space.World);
    }
    else if (CubePosDown_Z < 1.4)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, 0.14f, Space.World);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Почему при таче функция вызывается несколько раз?

Потому что `Input.GetTouch`, - возвращает все активные тачи.
Что бы отслеживать только новые можно, например, добавить такой код

```
if (touch.phase != TouchPhase.Began)
{
     return;
}
```

После добавления это кода вы получите телепортацию объекта по нажатию на экран

2. Как придать плавности движению куба при по оси Z?
   Есть много способов это сделать. Подробнее можно прочитать здесь: [Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)
   Например, мы можем все таки реагировать, не только на начала тача, но каждый раз при активном таче немножко сдвигать наш куб:

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, 0, Time.deltaTime * speed));
```

3. Нет никакого смысла делать `transform.Translate(0, 0, 0, Space.World);`
4. `Space.World` указывать можно, но это и так вариант по умолчанию
5. Ваши `tempUp` и `tempDown` удобнее заменить на одну переменную типа `bool`
   В итоге получиться что-то вроде:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Controller : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float CubePosUp_Z;
    private float CubePosDown_Z;
    private bool isUp; //Нужна?
    [SerializeField]
    private float speed = 1;

    private void Update()
    {
        var position = transform.position;
        CubePosUp_Z = position.z - 0.7f; //рекомендация: вынести все магические числа в поля класса
        CubePosDown_Z = position.z +  0.7f;
        
        if (Input.touchCount > 0)
        {
            Touch touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

            if (touch.position.y > Screen.height / 2f)
            {
                isUp = true;
                UpTran();
            }
            else
            {
                isUp = false;
                DownTran();
            }
        }
    }

    private void UpTran()
    {
        Debug.Log("Up");

        if (CubePosUp_Z > -1.4)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(0,0,-Time.deltaTime * speed));
        }
    }

    private void DownTran()
    {
        Debug.Log("Down");

        if (CubePosDown_Z < 1.4) //рекомендация: вынести все магические числа в поля класса
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(0,0,Time.deltaTime * speed));
        }
    }
}
```