# Как исправить прохождение объектов сквозь друг друга?

Tags: c#, unity3d

На двух объектах висят коллайдеры и Rigidbody с пометкой Discrete, мне надо чтобы плита откинула мяч под углом, но при определенной скорости мяч проходит сквозь плиту. Утолщал оба коллайдера, помогает, но частично, все равно при некоторых скоростях проходит мячик сквозь.

Comment: вся физика описана в Update а не FixedUpdate, угадал?

Comment: Установи у тела снаряда `Collision Detection` на `Continuous`.

Comment: Покажите скрипт.

Comment: Кстате, а где у коллайдера толщина задается?) Праздный интерес.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно выставить параметр Collision Detection на мяче в Continuous для непрерывного расчета столкновений через коллайдеры без Rigidbody, либо в Continuous Dynamic если на плите тоже есть Rigidbody. Если это не поможет, то можно еще уменьшить временной шаг в TimeManager.

Comment: Это плохое решение, которое, хоть и решает проблему костылем, но никак не решает корень проблемы. Не понимаю почему этот ответ плюсуют ибо это как советовать залепить целофаном дыру вместо того что бы вставить лобовое стекло в авто. С меня минус за такую медвежью услугу автору вопроса. Anton Nikolaev и aepot явно просекли в чем проблема)

Comment: @Andrew я же не против, предложите лучшее решение. Это действительно костыль который работает через раз, но он работает, если найдете лучшее решение, то я буду вам очень признателен.  А всем кто попытался ответь поднял рейтинг потому что просто благодарен людям которые уделили время и попытались помочь...

Comment: ответь на вопросы из комментариев, тебе укажут где твоя проблема не костылем. Но ты же не ответил) Они не просто так не дали это решение(которое наверняка известно им), а задали уточняющие вопросы. А еще ты практически наверняка сам поймешь где налажал если прочитаешь вот это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа