# Unity. Проблема с передвижением персонажа

Tags: unity3d

Я первый раз что-либо делаю в Unity и возникла проблема. Я решил что-либо сделать по гайдам из интернета. Код передвижения написан вроде бы правильно, но этот коричневый квадрат не двигается. Почему так может быть?
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;

    private Rigidbody2D Rb;
    private Vector2 MoveInput;
    private Vector2 MoveVelocity;

    void start()
    {
        Rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        MoveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        MoveVelocity = MoveInput.normalized * speed;
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Rb.MovePosition(Rb.position + MoveVelocity * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
}
```

[image: вот Unity и объект, который должен передвигаться]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Comment: Научись основам. Ты не понимаешь что делаешь от слова совсем.

Answer (score 0):

Убедитесь, что Input.GetAxisRaw имеет значение отличающееся от 0. Это можно сделать с помощью:

```
Debug.log(new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical")));
```

Стоит отметить, что GetAxisRaw требует ввода:
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html

Убедитесь также, что во время запуска находитесь во вкладке Game.