# Как перемещать 2D объект по оси на определенное количество координат заданное скриптом Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Мне нужно просто префаб квадрата изображения перемещать на определенное количество пунктов по оси Y, пробовал .transform.position.y+1, перемещается на произвольное количество пунктов.  Я понимаю что все это вектора и т.д. Но неужели нельзя в 2D, просто перемещать указав след координату в int?

Comment: Странный вопрос в котором уже есть ответ. Ты же сам написал `пробовал .transform.position.y+1`. Так в чем проблема передвигать на столько, сколько тебе нужно. А может ты вообще двигаешь UI элемент, которому нужно менять `anchoredPosition`, но не сказал об этом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете двигать объект через  `transform.position.y += 1`, потому что это, как вы сами и написали, вектор.

Можно менять позицию объекта напрямую (телепортация):

```
transform.position = new Vetor3(transform.position.x, 54); // Устанавливаем Y
transform.position += new Vector3(0, 10); // Увеличиваем Y на 10
```

Можно передвигать объект разными функциями (ссылки в конце):

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(Vector3 from, Vector3 to, float step);
transform.Translate(Vector3 vector);
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(Vector3 start, Vector3 target, float t);
GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(); // Если ваш объект физический
GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector3(...); // Если ваш объект - UI
```

Подробно эта тема освещалась пользователем Andrew здесь: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0)

> Ссылки: [Transform.Translate](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Translate.html), [Vector3.MoveTowards](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.MoveTowards.html), [Vector3.Lerp](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html), [RIgidbody.AddForce](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html), [RectTransform.anchoredPosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddForce.html)

Comment: Проблема далеко не в векторе, через transform.position.y **можно** двигать объект. проблема в том, что автор присваивает значение типа int, а vector имеет float

Comment: Ответ является неправильным, я бы советовал удалить данный ответ, что бы не вводить в заблуждение других пользователей

Comment: да, сори, щас чекнул и вправду выдаёт ошибку)

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer :) Кстати, насчет вашего варианта о написании 1f вместо 1: в С# int *может* **неявно** преобразовываться во float. Читайте [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/numeric-conversions#implicit-numeric-conversions). И вообще `Любой целочисленный тип неявно преобразуется в любой числовой тип с плавающей запятой.` Кстати, удалите, пожалуйста, комментарии не относящиеся к сути вопроса/ответа

Comment: @Mr.AntonDer Интересно. а это ваш минус на моем ответе? 

Comment: Да, забыл удалить)

Comment: спасибо помогло .GetComponent<RectTransform>().anchoredPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x ... , ... );