# Движение в Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю движение танка WSAD в void FixedUpdate() отслеживаю нажатие клавиши и с помощью физической силы двигаю в стороны.

`transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speedTank);` - Нефизическое движение работает но при столкновении с стеной проходит сквозь, получается оно мне не подходит.

`_rb.AddForce(Vector3.forward * speedTank, ForceMode.Acceleration);` - Работает только по мировым координатом, и когда у меня камера смотрит в другую сторону (к слову камера накинута на персонажа танк и следит за ним сверху) управление сбивается, при нажатии W танк едет вверх по мировым координатам без учёта поворота.

```
public Rigidbody _rb; // Плеер
 
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
    {
        _rb.AddForce(0, 0, speedTank);
    }
}
```

Вопрос: Как сделать физическое движение не в мировых координатах а с учётом куда смотрит камера игрока.
Вопрос 2: Как ограничить ускорение объекта, ибо если зажать клавишу юнит будет ускоряться почти до бесконечности, а мне нужно небольшое ускорение. С массой и графитацией игрался, как то криво всё получается.

P.S. Данную статью изучил, не помогает так как движение в мировых координатах
[Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026)

Comment: Есть такая вещь как transform.forward (просто убери координату `Y` и нормализируй вектор). Подставь его вместо Vector3.forward

Comment: Поставь моему ответу правильность или нет. Почему он висит как не решенный

Comment: Чтобы принять ответ, нужно поставить галочку, расположенную слева от ответа.

Answer (score 3):

Ну примерно так ты сможешь понять куда камера смотрит

```
Vector3 forward = Camera.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
forward.y = 0;
forward = forward.normalized;
```

Потом обрабатываешь нажатие клавиш и меняешь velocity

```
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W))
{
    _rb.velocity = forward * speedTank;
}
if(Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.W))
{
    _rb.velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
}
```

Чтобы назад идти делаешь `-forward`, а по бокам ты берешь `_camera.right` и `-_camera.right`, где | _camera > Transform |, чтобы через Camera.main не обращаться.

Не знаю на счет правильности, но работать должно