# Как правильно реализовать движение персонажа в сторону куда смотрит камера?

Tags: unity3d

Всем привет, на персонаже висит Cinemachine, движение осуществляется с помощью Addforce.
Персонаж нормально поворачивается в сторону куда смотрит камера и движется туда, но стоит посмотреть в землю персонаж сразу останавливается, так как пытается через нее пройти. Как это можно исправить?

P.S. вид от 3-го лица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотри на мой ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1249712/Движение-в-unity-3d/1249739#1249739)

Comment: @Methorn спасибо, но у я уже сам додумался все таки)