# Машина едет не так, как хотелось бы

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-android, controller

Машина в Юнити (3D под андроид) при управлении джойстиком двигается вперед хорошо, но назад - только в том случае, если скорость движения вперед уменьшается до 0, при отрицательных значениях снова начинает двигаться вперед.
Менял upDownMove на отрицательное значение, не помогло, саму скорость минусовал - ещё хуже.
В Гугле всё обшарил. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
void Update()
{
    upDownMove = joystick.Direction.y;
    rightLeftMove = joystick.Direction.x;

    transform.position += new Vector3((joystick.Direction.y * speed * Time.deltaTime), 0, -(joystick.Direction.x * speedRightLeft * Time.deltaTime));
 
    if (upDownMove == 0)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3((speed * Time.deltaTime), 0, -(joystick.Direction.x * speedRightLeft * Time.deltaTime));
    }

    if (upDownMove != 0)
    {
        speed += 0.1f * upDownMove;
        if (speed >= maxSpeed)
        {
            speed = maxSpeed;
        } 
    }
    else
    {
        if (speed > 0)
        {
            speed -= 1f;
            if (speed < 0)
            {
                speed = 0f;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            speed += 1f;
            if (speed > 0)
            {
                speed = 0f;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Смотри. У тебя позиция машинки задаётся через transform - так лучше не делать.
Разбей машинку на корпус и колёса. К корпусу колёса присоедени через WheelJoint Затем на корпус повесь скрипт, который будет управлять ими, в нём сделай два массива с колёсами(или четыре объекта - по каждому на колесо, но через массив удобнее) один из которых будет отвечать за рулевые колёса, а другой за задние колёса. Как реализовывать их вращение, почитай здесь - [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0)

В итоге получится вполне достоверная машина.

Upd. Обновляй физику в FixedUpdate.

Comment: Если необходимо было готовое решение, то извини, ищи сам или иди на youtube. Да и если немного поискать, то можно найти готовые скрипты которые можно переделать под себя(а то и готовый вариант найти)

Comment: Понял, пасибо))