# Почему при столкновении один Rigidbody немного входит в другой?

Tags: unity3d, обработка-столкновений

Есть 2 объекта: 1 - Rigidbody2D и Boxcollider, 2 - Boxcollider. Если объектом 1 толкать 2 в какую-либо сторону - все нормально, но как только объект 2 упирается в границу экрана, он останавливается, но объект 1 немного заходит во 2, если продолжать держать клавишу перемещения в нужном направлении. Что сделать, чтобы 1 не заходил во 2?
[image: Происходит это]

Это скрипт управления персонажем (если поможет)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        var moveInput = new Vector2(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),
            Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"));
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + moveInput.normalized * (speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }
}
```

Comment: Не видя вашего алгоритма и кода, можно сказать только "нужно просто исправление сделать, чтобы он этого не делал".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Comment: Да, вопрос тот же, но ответа на него по сути нет, человек написал перейти в такой-то подраздел, но там большой список непонятно чего