# Проблема с физикой в Unity(прыжки)

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда я зажимаю клавишу "W" и нажимаю пробел мой объект останавливается в воздухе. Как это исправить?
Вот код:

```cs
    public float speed = 5f;
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float jumpforse = 10f;
    public bool isGround = true;
    public BoxCollider bc;
    float deltaX;
    float deltaZ;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Move();
        
    }
    private void Move()
    {
        
        if (isGround == true)
        {
            deltaX = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * speed;
            deltaZ = Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * speed;
            if (deltaX > 0)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            }
            else if (deltaX == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.back * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            }
            if (deltaZ > 0)
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            }
            else if (deltaZ == 0)
            {

            }
            else
            {
                transform.Translate(Vector3.right * Time.deltaTime * speed);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space) && isGround == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(0, jumpforse, 0);
            isGround = false;
        }
        if (isGround == false && (deltaX != 0 || deltaZ != 0))
        {
            rb.AddForce(deltaX * Time.deltaTime * speed, 0, deltaZ * Time.deltaTime * speed);
        } 

        

    }
    
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider floor)
    {
        isGround = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте использовать AddForce еще и для передвижения, а не только для прыжка
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа

Comment: Проверьте ваш компонент ```RigidBody2D```, возможно у вас стоят галочки на против ```isKineMatic```, ```freeze rotation```, если они стоят то уберите иэ

Answer (score 1):

Учитесь по учебникам/курсам поэтапно, а не смотрите в интернетах, чё как делать варварски склеивая своего франкенштейна. Жизнь не проза, не оживёт и `hello mommy!` не скажет.

Конкретно ваш косяк в одновременном `transform.Translate` и `rb.AddForce`, одно физическое движение, другое скриптованное и существовать вместе они не могут. Плюс манипуляции с `transform` проходят сквозь стены, поскольку не имеют отношения к физике.

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]
// если компонент обязателен, указываем
[RequireComponent(typeof(Rigidbody))]

public class Character : MonoBehaviour
{
    // публичных полей тут быть не должно, это внутренняя кухня
    [SerializeField] private float _speed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float _jumpForce = 10f;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private KeyCode _jumpKey = KeyCode.Space;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask _floorLayer;
    private Rigidbody _body;
    private bool _isGround = true;
    // в полях deltaX и deltaY нет смысла 

    private void Awake ()
    {
        _body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }

    private void Update ()
    {
        MoveUpdate();
    }

    private void MoveUpdate ()
    {
        // eсли блок состоит из одной команды, то операционные скобки { } не обязательны!
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(_jumpKey))
            Jump();

        // для чего все if не понятно Axis и есть все 4 направления
        Vector2 Axis = new Vector2(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"), Input.GetAxis("Vertical"));
        Vector2 Velocity = Axis*_speed;
        // присваиваем телу скорости по плоскасти xz, не трогая y
        _body.velocity = new Vector3(Velocity.x, _body.velocity.y, Velocity.y);
    }

    private void Jump ()
    {
        if (_isGround)
        {
            _body.AddForce(0, _jumpForce, 0);
            _isGround = false;
        }
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter (Collision collision)
    {
        // что бы не заниматься фигнёй расставляя триггеры просто задаём полу конкретный Layer и указываем его
        // в испекторе прямо под именем GameObject
        if (collision.gameObject.layer == _floorLayer)
            _isGround = true;
    }
}
```