# Как сделать нормальную физику сталкивания игрока со стенами в unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Собственно проблема в том, что персонаж в одном кадре влезает в стену, потом просчитывается физика и его отпружинивает обратно. Пытался двигать и с помошью addforce, и изменяя velocity, и просто через transform.position, и в update и в fixedUpdate. Всё равно.

Сейчас сделал костыль. Пуская racast в право, и если расстояние до ближайшего коллайдера после изменения позиции игрока(до отрисовки) слишком маленькое, то есть игрок в стене, то двигаю игрока обратно к краю стены. Работает идеально. Но в реализации куча неприятностей. Основная проблема - лучей придётся пускать по несколько в каждую из 4 сторон. Это довольно запарно.

Если есть какой-то более адекватный способ сделать хорошую физику, поставить там какую-то галочку в rigitbody, или всё же я не разобрался, и можно как-то сделать это с обычной физикой unity. Буду очень благодарен, если пришлёте готовый скрипт управления персонажем, где учтены эти тонкости.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0) Там внизу моего вопроса/ответа самый последний скриншот - и есть ответ на твой вопрос.

Comment: Но вообще при физическом движении такого обычно быть не должно. Вероятно у тебя слишком большая скорость или еще что-то странное в проекте. Но тот костыль тебе поможет.

Comment: @Andrew почему вы каждый раз утверждаете, что Continuous CD - это костыль?

Comment: @RiotBr3aker потому что по-хорошему этим пользоваться нежелательно т.к. это более нагружает расчет физики. Если не утверждать что это костыль - люди начнут думать что это хорошая фича и хорошая практика и будут выставлять всюду где не попадя, а потом будут приходить сюда и спрашивать почему проэкт тормозит. Само собой не указывая это как важный нюанс, потому что даже не поймут что это важный нюанс. Ты хочешь с этим разбиратся? Лично я - нет. Чем меньше люди будут это использовать - тем лучше для них же.

Comment: @Andrew это какая-то надуманная причина, большинство 2D/3D игр используют рейкасты каждый фрейм для проверки нахождения на земле/в воздухе. Что, по факту, является ручным CCD, но костылем это не считается. Поэтому, пожалуйста, не нужно называть решение костылем просто потому что оно "медленное", особенно если речь идет про 1 объект.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker речь идет про один обект только теоретически. SO ищется другими людьми, а не только автором вопроса. В том числе и новичками, которые двигают своих персонажей абы как. И которые будут ставить CCD не на один обьект, а всюду потому что так лучше выглядит. И они же будут здесь мусорить новыми темами о томозах проекта на очередном девайсе. И без того что бы открыть проэкт и просмотреть настройки никто им не поможет с этим. А на SO это делать никто не будет. Проблема с реализацией движения - это то с чем буквально сталкивается КАЖДЫЙ кто садится за юнити.

Comment: @Andrew написать физически корректный контроллер сможет далеко не каждый профессионал движка, что уж говорить о новичках. Проблема в том, что CCD - это не костыль, а вполне легальная реализация. Как, по-вашему, шутеры с поддержкой баллистики работают? Или все последние части Battlefield/Call of duty 2019 - это костыльные проекты, сделанные новичками?

Comment: Я думаю что CCD должны использоватся аккуратно и осознанно и только там, где это реально необходимо. Ответ же про костыль оставляется для новичков, а не для тех кто пишет игры ААА класса. В том что люди на таких проэктах в лишнем месте не поставят CCD я и так уверен.

Comment: @Andrew действительно, поставил continuous collision detection в rigitbody, и всё начало работать так, как нужно. В моём понимании, continuous collision позволяет быстрым объектам не пролетать сквозь стены. И, если честно, не очень понятно, почему это помогло исправить мою проблему.

Comment: И если несложно, оставьте это как ответ, я помечу решением.

Comment: Я так понял, ты используешь rigitbody??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rigitbody -> Collision Detection -> Continuous

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте делать это все в LateUpdate().