# Проблема с прыжками в Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я в Unity недавно(только 2 дня) учусь по видео урокам. Делаю все как показано на видео, но персонаж прыгает только в определенных местах платформы(всегда с право). Создаю платформер.
Вот код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;


public class plaeyr : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 3f;
    [SerializeField] private int lives = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float jumpForse = 15f;
    private bool isGrounded = false;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        CheckGround();
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>();

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
            run();
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && isGrounded)
            Jump();
    }
    private void run() {
        Vector3 dir = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + dir, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        sprite.flipX = dir.x < 0.0f;

    }
    private void Jump() {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpForse, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
    private void CheckGround() {
        Collider2D[] collider = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(transform.position, 0.3f);
        isGrounded = collider.Length > 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Понятия не имею в чем именно проблема, но меня явно смущает одна строка из этого кода.

Попробуй заменить строку:

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W) && isGrounded)
```

на строку

```
if ( isGrounded && ( Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") || Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.W)) )
```

---

Оффтоп:
хоть код и относительно неплохой в этом видеоуроке (что на самом деле редкость, хотя есть и огрехи - например только прыжок на физике сделан, но передвижение - нет), но я настоятельно рекомендую сначала ознакомится с вот этим [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0) перед тем как продолжать дальше