# Плохая синхронизации между MeshCollider и CapsuleCollider

Tags: c#, unity3d

Всем привет

Я делаю что-то на подобии CS:GO, ток на телефоны.

В интернете я нашёл карты в **.bsp** формате, далее, через прогу я перегоняю это в **.obj** и через другую прогу прогоняю в **.fbx**

> В .fbx формате Unity сама подгоняет текстуры, это удобно!

При импорте карты в Unity я ставлю галочка напротив пункта: **Generate Collider** (Или что то типо такого) у самой модели

Игрок, у которого **CapsuleCollider** взаимодействует с картой нормально, но если начать подходить к каким-нибудь углам и прижиматься, то он проходит сквозь эти углы (Сначала тряска и бац...)

Движение персонажа реализовано через **transform.position**

Может кто сталкивался с таким и знает как пофисить?

Comment: `Движение персонажа реализовано через transform.position` быть может в этом и проблема https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/936027/373567, я даже закрою этот вопрос как дубликат. Потому что в ответе по ссылке прямым текстом написано, что transform.position делать не надо.

Comment: @aepot спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Если вы делаете на телефоны, то забудьте про MeshCollider, тем более на таком огромном объекте, как карта. Коллайдеры всей карты надо разделить на простейшие - Шар, Куб и т.д. Просчет MeshCollider-а очень ресурсозатратен и не всегда работает так, как Вам хочется.

Comment: Карта там +- меленькая и примитивная, из cs 1.6

Comment: Даже на слабых телефонах не лагает, тестил)

Comment: Всё же я советую Вам отказаться от MeshCollider. Поверьте моему опыту, Вы с ним в перспективе сильно намучаетесь. Лучше потратить время и сделать всё примитивными коллайдерами.