# Как реализовать отталкивание от границ

Tags: c#, unity3d

Столкнулся с проблемой, а заключается она в том, что я хочу сделать так, чтобы при попытке перейти поле огражденнное каменными плитами персонажа отталкивало от поля в сторону. Может быть знает кто решение на эту проблему (если можно детальнее)?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: при столкновении берешь направление игрока, умножаешь на -1 и даешь импулс

Comment: А можешь это описать в пару строчек кода?

Comment: Для этого уже есть гугл

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/936027/373567

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как сделать плавное отталкивание от стен?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1301822/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd)