# При движении одного объекта вверх, второй, стоящий на нем, начинает дергаться, немного проходя через текстуру [Unity 2D]

Tags: unity3d

[Видео с проблемой](https://youtu.be/KDduFRZ_Kr8)

Движение платформы задал в FixedUpdate, функцией

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, speed, 0));
```

У самого игрока я поставил:

Collision Detection -> Continuous

Interpolate -> Interpolate

(Не уверен, что они на что-то повлияли)

При обычном движении такого не замечал

Edit 1:
Заменил FixedUpdate на обычный Update
И умножил вектор на Time.deltaTime и на 200

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, speed, 0) * Time.deltaTime * 200);
```

Это замедлило сам "лифт", но теперь выглядит все гораздо плавнее. Только все равно игрок попадает в текстуру немного. Чем выше скорость, тем больше игрок попадает в текстуру.

[Это можно как-то исправить или придется с этим смириться?(кликабельно)](https://youtu.be/b2nOzAPN4Ow)

[Вот, что происходит, если увеличить скорость в 10 раз](https://youtu.be/QcxBJsN2DGI)

Edit 2:

Решено:) Спасибо Максим Фисман и Yaroslav

Обратно вернул FixedUpdate

Вместо

```
transform.Translate(new Vector3(0, speed, 0));
```

Поставил

```
rb.MovePosition(transform.position + new Vector3(0, speed, 0) * Time.deltaTime * speed2);
```

Инспектор у "лифта"

[image: Инспектор у "лифта"]

Comment: FixedUpdate обычно используется для физики, а не для Translate.

Comment: При обычном Update там все раза в два страшнее)

Comment: Изменение `transform` это телепортация, для движения есть `rigidbody`.

Comment: Вам нужно использовать физику (вы ведь хотите, чтобы кубы лежали друг на друге по законам физики!) . Читайте [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0). А вообще я думаю, что этот вопрос можно закрыть как дубликат вопроса по ссылке. Что думаете?

Comment: Да, мне не было изначально известно как искать решение.