# Поворот объекта с камерой мышкой C# Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d, мышь

Я делаю поворот объекта с камерой передвижением мышки, как в шутерах. Моя камера находится в двух родительских элементах. Верхний по иерархии из них - `Player` имеет параметр RigidBody. Делая поворот объекта, я поворачиваю элемент RigidBody из `Player`.

```
-Player
---PlayerSkin
-----PlayerCamera
```

Код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Moving : MonoBehaviour{

    // Preferences
    public GameObject PlayerCamera; // Camera
    public GameObject Player; // Object with Rigidbody
    // Player
    private Rigidbody rb;
    public float speed;
    // Mouse control
    private float MouseX;
    private float MouseY;
    public float mouseSpeed;

 

    void Start(){
        rb = Player.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        speed = 3;
        mouseSpeed = 5;
    }

    void Update(){
        // Mouse Abort
        MouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        MouseY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
        transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(MouseY, MouseX, 0);






        // Move Forward
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)){
            rb.transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Move Back
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)){
            rb.transform.Translate(Vector3.back * speed * Time.deltaTime);  
        }

        // Move Right
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)){
            rb.transform.Translate(Vector3.right * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        // Move Left
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)){
            rb.transform.Translate(Vector3.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
        }

    }
    
}
```

Поворот работает. Но если переменная `mouseSpeed` имеет значение больше 90, поворот становится резкий и нестабильный, а также если поворачивать камеру по Y то сам объект передвигается по X.

Почему так происходит, и есть ли способ избежать этого?

Comment: Quaternion.Euler(MouseY, MouseX, - у тебя х и у поменяны местами

Comment: Кроме того у тебя при привоении MouseY для чего-то идет минус. Для чего он там?

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, я поменял местами MouseY и MouseX, но теперь у меня все перепуталось - при повороте по Y меняется X и наоборот.
Минус у `Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")` для того что бы убрать инверсию мыши.

Comment: Значит ты дополнительно сделал что-то неправильно в ином месте. Потому что Х это первый аргумент функции, а У - второй.

Comment: а еще ты уверен что там *= а не += должно быть? Вероятнее всего это причина слишом большого скачка скорости. Я вот логически не могу предположить почему там умножение

Comment: А еще просмотри тему о пережвижении персонажа, у тебя здесь передвижение нефизическое и его желательно заменить на физическое.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа/936027#936027

Comment: Andrew, ошибок связанных с порядком аргументов в коде я не нашел, код то маленький. В том что в присвоении должно быть именно *= я не уверен, по этому поставил += и получил ошибку - `CS0019: Operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Quaternion' and 'Quaternion'`.
Спасибо за ссылку на вопрос, обязательно прочитаю.

Comment: важно иное, взгляни на документацию к методу 
Quaternion.Euler и увидишь что икс это первый аргумент.. И странно с этим спорить. Это явно означает что ты где-то начудилв ином месте раз сунешь туда Y. Что до '+=' - это тоже не аргумент. Это намек на то что нужно добавлять иным способом.  А вот умножение здесь мне кажется весьма стремным хаком. Если ты не можешь обьяснить для чего конкретно ты использовал умножение в этом месте а не иной способ - это значит что ты подбирал метдом тыка.

Comment: И раз уж ты подбирал методом тыка а не обдумано поставил это - не стоит удивлятся с того что у тебя после какого-то значения код ведет себя странно. Это нормальное последствие твоего способа написание кода.

Comment: Вы правы, я нашел этот код на форумах и сайтах, и не до конца понял его работу. По этому изучу метод Quaternion.Euler по вашему совету, в документациях. Спасибо вам за ответ и за направление к решению.