# Не работает изменение скорости unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-editor

Вот есть скрипт, в котором есть 2 действия, изменяющие скорость - бег и приседание. Но почему - то всегда работает только одно из них, а другое игнорируется. В чем дело?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform camera;

private void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        speed = 15;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            speed = 6;
    }
    else
    {
        speed = 6;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        camera.localPosition = new Vector3(0, -2, 0);
        speed = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        camera.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        speed = 6;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        transform.localPosition += transform.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime;
    }
  }

}
```

В консоли ничего

Comment: вообще советую изначально ознакомиться с вот этой статьей https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0 а уже потом пытаться реализовать логику движения. Удалить этот. Переделать код на новую систему. И если все еще будут вопросы - тогда уже пересоздашь этот вопрос уже с кодом на новой системе)

Comment: А то здесь много "детских ошибок" в коде. И его исправлять вместо посылания читать статью - это тебе делать зло потому что ты все равно упрешся в иные проблемы этого кода рано или поздно

Comment: Дайте угадаю, у Вас скорость всегда либо 0, либо 6? И никогда не бывает 15?

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский Да, именно так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась, когда сделал эти изменения кода:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = 15;
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
            speed = 6;
    }
    else if(!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
    {
        speed = 6;
    }

    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        camera.localPosition = new Vector3(0, -2, 0);
        speed = 2;
    }
    else if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        camera.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно понял о чем речь и проблема в том, что ты пытаешься увеличить скорость и присесть одновременно, то ошибка в логике условий (ниже в коде цитирую их), поэтому оба действия и не могут быть выполнены:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && !Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
```

Comment: а чем они противоречат? В одном случае если лефт шифт нажат но не нажат лефт контрол. В ином случае наоборот. Никаого противоречия

Comment: @Andrew если я правильно понял - речь об одновременном нажатии, других вариантов не может быть.

Comment: Существуют 3 ситуации: 1 контрал + шифт.  2 Только шифт. 3 только контрал. Ты берешь в своей голове первую. Он же в коде описал 2 последующих. Хоть и не лучшим и не оптимальным способом (лучше это было бы сделать через конструкцию "else if"). На самом деле у автора достаточно заплутанный код и что конкретно он хотел сделать вообще неясно до конца) Но утверждать что эти 2 конструкции неправильны и противоречат - точно неправильно)

Comment: @Andrew я не имею ввиду что они неправильные, сейчас поправлю для ясности ответ, я имею ввиду, что если он имел ввиду одновременное нажатие - то у него условия противоречат друг другу:)

Comment: @Andrew как видишь, человек добавил себе ответ о котором я и предположил, но не пометил мое решение как верное, а меня еще и минусанул кто-то)))