# Персонажа дергает при контакте с объектом(Если упираюсь и продолжаю идти в сторону объекта).И на нем и на объекте колайдер

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RubyCon : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;
    float horizontal;
    float vertical;

    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody2d = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        vertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 position = rigidbody2d.position;
        position.x = position.x + 3.0f * horizontal * Time.deltaTime;
        position.y = position.y + 3.0f * vertical * Time.deltaTime;

        rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);
    }
}
```

Comment: Дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0) Внимательно перечитай весь текст там - поймешь в чем проблема и как решается. Там расписано лучше чем кто-либо даст тебе прямой ответ в этом вопросе

Comment: Спасибо за наводку

Answer (score 1):

Добавь после `Rigidbody2D rigidbody2d;`:

`public float speed;`

И замени:

`position.x = position.x + 3.0f * horizontal * Time.deltaTime;`

На:

`rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2 (horizontal * speed, rigidbody2d.velocity.y);`

А также замени:

`position.y = position.y + 3.0f * vertical * Time.deltaTime;`

На:

`rigidbody2d.velocity = new Vector2 (rigidbody2d.velocity.x ,vertical * speed);`

В таком случае стоит убрать `Vector2 position = rigidbody2d.position;` и `rigidbody2d.MovePosition(position);`.

Помимо этого, твой персонаж может залипать на стенах, в таком случае возможно стоит убрать все коллайдеры и поставить Capsule collider.

Comment: у меня "rb" не распознается как rigidbody

Comment: Исправлено, но ты ведь и сам мог изменить rb на rigidbody2d...

Comment: В целом этот ответ хоть и не идеален, но должен пофиксить проблему. Не знаю кто минусонул - но он не прав что поставил минус. С меня плюс для востановления справедливости в мире)