# Как активировать переменную при передвижении?

Tags: c#, unity3d, анимация

Я программирую на c#. В unity я делаю анимацию. Что мне нужно вставить в условие, чтобы когда игрок перемещался активировалась переменная Walk?

Вот код:

```
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }
    public void Update()
    {
        moveInput = joystick.Horizontal;
        moveInput1 = joystick.Vertical;
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, moveInput1 * speed);
        if ()
        {
            anim.SetBool("Walk", true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("Walk", false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: [Операторы выбора. Справочник по C#](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/selection-statements)

Comment: @aepot Как делать условия, это понятно. Но, какое условие нужно сделать ,чтоы запускалась анимация при движении?

Comment: `if (rb.velocity != Vector2.zero)`?

Comment: @aepot Вы очень помогли! Создавайте ответ, отмечу как правильный

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Движения и прочие дела, не связанные с графикой обычно делаются в `FixedUpdate`

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(joystick.Horizontal * speed, joystick.Vertical * speed);
    anim.SetBool("Walk", rb.velocity != Vector2.zero);
}
```

[Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567)