# Передвижение и поворот врага в unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть вот такой код для передвижения врага туда-сюда от какой точки.
Вопрос. Как сделать, чтобы при повороте он останавливался на некоторое время, и только потом продолжил путь?

пока у него одно состояние, поэтому там только Moving().

```
public class enemi_1 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public int pointDistance;
    public Transform point;

    bool moveRight;
    private void Update()
    {
        Moving();
    }
    void Moving()
    {
        if (transform.position.x > point.position.x + pointDistance)
            moveRight = false;
        else if (transform.position.x < point.position.x - pointDistance)
            moveRight = true;

        if (moveRight)
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
        else
            transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

попытался исправить , но теперь он просто стопорится и не движется как только запускается IEnumerator Stop().

```
  void Moving()
    {
        if (transform.position.x > point.position.x + pointDistance)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Stop());
            moveRight = false;
        }
        else if (transform.position.x < point.position.x - pointDistance)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Stop());
            moveRight = true;
        }

        if (!stop)
        {
            if (moveRight) 
                transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);

            else 
                transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
        }
    }
    IEnumerator Stop()
    {
        stop = true;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(stopTime);
        stop = false;
    }
```

Comment: Будет полезным к прочтению https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0

Comment: Вопрос не решит - но будет полезным. А задачу можно решить через корутины. Условно корутиной засекаешь 1 секунду и в это время флагом запрещаешь двигаться в методе мувинг пока флаг равен тру

Comment: попытался исправить не вышло (

Comment: наверное потому что ты запускаешь кучу корутин которые навеки стопают твоего персонажа?

Answer (score 0):

Приблизительно так.

Код не тестировал и даже не писал в редактор так что могут быть логические и синтаксические ошибки

```
    var movingEnabled = true;

    var isOnTheLeftEdge: Bool  { get { transform.position.x < point.position.x - pointDistance }}
    var isOnTheRightEdge: Bool { get { transform.position.x > point.position.x + pointDistance }}

    void Moving()
    {
        if (movingEnabled)
        {
            if (isOnTheLeftEdge)
            { 
                StartCoroutine(DisableMove());
                moveRight != moveRight;
                //возможно здесь нужен доп. MoveRight();
            } else if (isOnTheRightEdge) {
                StartCoroutine(DisableMove());
                moveRight != moveRight;
                //возможно здесь нужен доп. MoveLeft();
            }

            if (moveRight) {
                MoveRight();
            } else {
                MoveLeft();
            }
        }
    }

    private void MoveLeft() {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    }

    private void MoveRight() {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    }

    IEnumerator DisableMove()
    {
        movingEnabled = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(stopTime);
        movingEnabled = true;
    }
```

А еще ты так и не прочел ссылку которую я скинул. Потому что ты все еще телепортируешь персонажа в своем коде (соответственно и я это не переписывал)