# Как обнаружить обьект перед персонажем | Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

В чем идея:
Персонаж двигается по тайлам в размере 1 метра, и когда перед ним есть стена он просто в нее входит, а нужно чтобы он не двигался дальше

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerControler : MonoBehaviour {

    public float MoveSpeed = 1.5f;
    private int RotateStage = 0;
    private Vector3 To;

    private void Start(){
        To = transform.position;
    }

    private void Update(){
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Q)){if(RotateStage <= 2){ RotateStage = RotateStage + 1; Debug.Log("Rotated!"); }else{ RotateStage = RotateStage = 0; Debug.Log("Rotated!"); }}
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)){if(RotateStage >= 1){ RotateStage = RotateStage - 1; Debug.Log("Rotated!"); }else{ RotateStage = RotateStage = 3; Debug.Log("Rotated!"); }}
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            if(RotateStage == 0){To.x = To.x + 1;}
            if(RotateStage == 1){To.z = To.z + 1;}
            if(RotateStage == 2){To.x = To.x - 1;}
            if(RotateStage == 3){To.z = To.z - 1;}
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate() {transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, To, MoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);}
}
```

Скрины сцены:[image: вот]

Comment: Вот решение: не двигать персонажа, если перед ним есть стена. Очень мало информации. Где код передвижения, чтобы понимать как вы вообще двигаете персонажа? Где информация о том, как вы с тайлами работаете?

Comment: @KOTlK - Я пересоздам вопрос со всей информацией

Comment: исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Узнаю код, я вам еще раньше писал, что вы не двигаете объект, а телепортируете. Двигайте объект при помощи физики и таких проблем не будет.

Comment: если я нехочу двигать обьект физикой? могу вознимать проблемы ломающие перемещение

Comment: Тогда делайте рейкаст в сторону, куда персонаж будет двигаться и проверяйте, есть там стена или нет. Вообще это все выглядит как огромный костыль. В юнити есть нормальные тайлы (гуглите Tilemaps), а не просто 3д кубы. На начальном уровне вам проще будет обучиться на них, а позже уже делать свою реализацию.

Comment: в смысле могут возникать проблемы ломающие перемещение? Наоборот проблем с физикой будет значительно меньше.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Answer (score 1):

Сделать впереди обьекта триггер и если что то в нем будет(допустим обьект с именем стена), то отключить возможность передвежения. Надеюсь правильно понял

1. Добавьте на стену **RigidBody** и колайдер
2. Сделайте впереди объекта, который передвигается колайдер(в настройках колайдера нажмите на галочку IsTrigger)
3. Реализуйте следующие в скрипте с управлением игроком

Код

```
{
   void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
   {

     //Если в триггер зашел объект с именем стена
     if(other.gameObject.name == "wall") 
     {
       /*Код, который сделает невозможным дальнейшее передвижение 
       игрока*/
     }
}  }
```