# Персонаж плавно "слетает" с объектов при ходьбе вперёд с пропасти (метод Velocity)

Tags: unity3d

Если на краю обрыва зажать движение вперёд, то герой плавно пойдёт вперёд, при этом почти не снижаясь, уже миллион сайтов и форумов облазил но ничего не нашёл.

вот мой код

```
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerMove : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody rb;
    [SerializeField] int MoveSpeed;
    [SerializeField] int SprintSpeed;
    public float JumpPower = 1f;
    protected bool onGround = true;
    private void Start()
    {rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>(); }
    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {   if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Ground")
            { onGround = true; }}
    private void FixedUpdate()
    { 
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space) && (onGround))
            { rb.AddForce(transform.up * JumpPower);
            onGround = false; }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = transform.forward * SprintSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime; }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = (transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime) + (transform.right * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = (transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime) + (-transform.right * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = (-transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime) + (transform.right * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = (-transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime) + (-transform.right * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime); }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime; }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = -transform.forward * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime; }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = transform.right * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime; }

        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A) && (onGround))
            { rb.velocity = -transform.right * MoveSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Этого не хватит для понимания проблемы. Плюс управление очень странное, я думаю так никто и никогда не делает. И впринцыпе не понятно, что у вас за игра. Переделайте пожалуйста вопрос

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Comment: У вас передвижение вообще непонятно как реализовано, выше ссылка, посмотрите туда, затем [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/416584/%d0%9a%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%b8-%d0%b8-%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b1%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%83%d1%80%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-c)