# Unity2D: Объект игнорирует коллайдеры при MoveTowards

Tags: unity3d, перемещение, коллизии

Программируя в Unity мне стало необходимо сделать перемещение объекта по точкам. Для этого я использовал MoveTowards. Таких объектов на сцене несколько, все они подразумеваются, как люди. Но вот незадача: этот объект напрочь игнорирует другие такие же объекты, хотя на каждом висит и Collider, и RigidBody. Эти объекты, то есть люди, даже игнорируют другие объекты, созданные мной в качестве препятствий с помощью стандартных ассетов Unity, например, квадрат. Все объекты находятся на одном значении Z.

В чем я допускаю ошибку?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Transform[] _waypoints;
    [SerializeField] int _speed;

    private int _currentWaypointIndex;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (_waypoints != null)
        {
            if (_currentWaypointIndex == _waypoints.Length)
            {
                _waypoints = null;
                return;
            }

            Transform target = _waypoints[_currentWaypointIndex];

            if (transform.position == target.position)
            {
                _currentWaypointIndex++;
            }

            transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, _speed * Time.deltaTime);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ваша проблема в том, что вы не двигаете объект, а телепортируете его. Используйте для движения свойство velocity компонента Rigidbody/Rigidbody2D и проблем с коллизией не будет.

Answer (score 0):

Суть проблемы заключалась в неправильном подходе к перемещению объекта, о чем мне сказал человек в комментарии. Я также нашел хороший ответ, который не сразу понял, в котором хорошо объясняются азы перемещения объекта: [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/Правильная-реализация-передвижения-персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0)