# Как в Unity заставить моего персонажа двигаться прямо, когда применяется camera perspective?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Вопрос касается разработки в Unity3D.

Когда я удерживаю клавишу (W)forward в левой или в правой части экрана, мой игровой персонаж не движется прямо вперед, он движется по диагонали. Это происходит потому что к сцене применяется перспектива камеры которая заставляет моего персонажа выглядеть так, как будто он движется по диагонали.

Как заставить моего персонажа двигаться прямо, когда применяется camera perspective?

[Вот эффект, которого я пытаюсь избежать:](https://giant.gfycat.com/TameGleefulAsianlion.webm)

Ортографическая камера не рассматривается - эффект глубины исчезает и т.п.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

Comment: Вы движете персонажа относительно оси координат, x или z, а надо двигать относительно вектора направления камеры по азимуту в плоскости xz. Но так делают обычно, когда камера следует за персонажем.

Comment: Вот описание проблемы которая возникла у меня и где автор "попытался" её решить. Но ответ так и не дали. Я писал автору который закрыл пост - но он не отвечает. https://answers.unity.com/questions/1640456/character-controller-for-fixed-perspective-camera.html

Comment: @aepot Не совсем понимаю как двигать относительно вектора направления по азимуту - есть ли примеры? У меня камера статична под углом 45 градусов - перемещается лишь объект по x и z.

Comment: При статичной камере то, как сейчас движется объект на вашем видео - выглядит нормально. Нарисуйте шахматку или сетку на плоскости по вектору камеры, то есть с отклонением 45 градусов, и поймете, почему. Не нужно ничего менять.

Comment: @aepot вы наверно не совсем поняли - на видео он движется нормально и правильно даже, но необходимо чтобы он перемещался вверх относительно краёв монитора при перспективной камере, а сейчас если он скраю и начинает двигается вверх то создается иллюзия что он движется по диагонали (то есть необходима некая формула поворота что-ли)

Comment: Нормально он двигается. Вы же слышали про углы обзора и т.д. для перспективы? Хотите уменьшить эффект линзы, отдалите камеру, раза в 2 назад от объекта и так же раза в 2 увеличьте зум, то есть приблизьте центр картинки, должно помочь.