# Неправильно передвигается куб

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пишу платформер на Unity.
При нажатии на кнопку "вперед" куб вращается, передвигаясь по сцене.
А если зажать "вперед" и "вправо", он перестает вращаться, просто изменяя свои координаты.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
  public float Speed = 10f;
  private Rigidbody _rb;

  void Start()
  {
      _rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
  }

  void FixedUpdate()
  {
    float moveHorizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    float moveVertical = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(moveHorizontal, 0.0f, moveVertical);

    _rb.AddForce(movement * Speed);
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R))
    {  
  SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }
  }
  private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if(this.CompareTag("Player") && other.CompareTag("Finish"))
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
            
        }
    }
}
```

Ограничить нажатия кнопок не помогает, проблема возникает также если куб повернут углом вперед, т.е. на 45 градусов
UPD: перенаправили на ссылку [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0), пост не помог, проблема осталась

Comment: Делаете много лишней работы. Не стоит каждый раз вызывать `GetComponent`, ведь он в вашем случае всегда возвращает одно и то же. Сделайте это один раз в `Start()` и сoхраните в поле.

Comment: Я только начинающий, и это мой первый код, но за совет спасибо, код исправил

Comment: Вопрос переоткрыл, отредактируйте его, обновите код внутри. А лучше скрипт целиком вставьте.

Comment: На данном сайте есть очень хорошая статья посвященная передвижению. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0