# Не прыгает персонаж Unity 3D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Делаю простенький мобильный шутер от первого лица на Unity. Изначально основные механики передвижения сделал на сфере, в том числе и прыжок. Всё работало шикарно, но после добавления анимации персонаж стал прыгать "через раз". причем анимация проигрывается всегда, а вот прыжок происходит приблизительно раз в три нажатия.
Возможно что то не так в коде?

```
public void OnClickJump()
    {
        if (ch_controller.isGrounded)
            gravityForce = jumpPower;
        anim.SetTrigger("Jump");
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

Answer (score 0):

Проверь Анимациию Прыжка СКОРЕЕ Всего когда твой персонаж прыгает то он своей анимациияй
Задивает земли или застривает в ней

Или используй другой вариант прыжка а именно

```
rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpForce, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

я надеюсь ты знаешь что rb это Rigidbody

на всякий случай если ты не знаешь то ты пишешь это:

```
void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
```