# Unity3D, C# помогите пожалуйста настроить взаимодействие персонажа с объектами из blender

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сейчас персонаж (тоже из blender) проходит сквозь объекты, а нужно чтобы он останавливался при взаимодействии. При чём с некоторыми объектами можно взаимодействовать. Вот код основного персонажа:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public CharacterController controller;
    public LayerMask groundMask;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float speed = 5f;
    public float gravity = -19.6f;
    public float groundDistance = 0.01f;
    public float jumpHeight = 1f;
    Vector3 velocity;
    bool isGrounded;
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);
        if (isGrounded == true && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }
        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");



        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        controller.Move(move * speed * Time.deltaTime);

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        if (Input.GetKey("c"))
        {
            controller.height = 1f;
        }
        else
        {
            controller.height = 2f;
        }
        if (Input.GetKey("left shift"))
        {
            speed = 9f;
        }
        else
        {
            speed = 5f;
        }
    }
}
```

Может дело не в коде, вот скриншот настроек:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На объектах есть коллайдеры ?

Comment: начни с изучения вот этого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0/936027#936027 Когда реализуешь передвижение персонажа правильно, а так же повесишь коллайдер на персонажа - все будет ок