# Проблема с Time.deltatime

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть такой код. При умножении _speed на Time.deltatime у лазеров разная скорость. Убираю - одинаковая скорость. Пересмотрела ролики по дельте - вроде корректно использую. В чем проблема здесь, подскажите, пожалуйста

```
void Update()
{
    _timer += Time.deltaTime;

    if (_timer > _shotDelay && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.X))
    {
        _timer = 0;
        Shoot();
    }
}

private void Shoot()
{
    GameObject NewLaserLeft = Instantiate(_laserPrefab, _gunPositionLeft);
    GameObject NewLaserRight = Instantiate(_laserPrefab, _gunPositionRight);

    NewLaserLeft.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, _shotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    NewLaserRight.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity = new Vector3(0, 0, _shotSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

Comment: Домножать на время нужно, когда изменяешь позицию напрямую. Когда изменяешь velocity/addforce, физический движок сам двигает объект и сам применяет поправки на время. Тебе здесь не надо умножать скорость на deltaTime. И взаимодействие с физикой(velocity/addforce) производятся в FixedUpdate, а не в обычном апдейте.

Comment: Спасибо. Про физику в FU знаю, но не знаю, как код нормально написать для него. Поэтому в update сделала

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567 быть может это поможет разобраться

Comment: Читала это. Прочту еще раз. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в `deltaTime`, а в 0...

```
if (_timer > _shotDelay)
    _timer = 0;
```

А куда девается остаток? `deltaTime` при 60fps ровна ~1/60 (0,016 сек). При каждом обнулении ты теряешь до 0,016 секунд. Если выстрел раз в секунду, то через 10 секунд ты потеряешь до 0,16 секунд, что является рассинхроном, заметным невооруженным глазом, если это выполняется несколькими одновременно.

`Input.GetKeyDown` это момент нажатия. Вероятность, что именно в этот фрейм будет нажатие, ничтожная.

### Как написать стрельбу

```
public class FooGun : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float _fireRate = 0.5f;
    [Space]
    [SerializeField] private Transform _shootPoint;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject _bulletTemplate;
    private IEnumerator _firing;

    public bool IsFire { get; private set; }

    public void StartFire ()
    {
        if (IsFire)
            return;
        IsFire = true; // меняем флаг стрельбы 
        // если корутина не запущена, запускаем
        if (_firing == null)
        {
            _firing = Firing();
            StartCoroutine(_firing);
        }
    }

    public void StopFire ()
    {
        if (IsFire == false)
            return;
        // меняем флаг стрельбы, но не останавливаем корутину,
        // поскольку стральба может начаться вновь до 
        // истечения времени между выстрелами
        IsFire = false;
    }

    private IEnumerator Firing ()
    {
        float elapsed = _fireRate; // на старте стреляет сразу
        while (true)
        {
            // время стрелять
            // при очень высоком темпе стрельбы может быть несколько пуль за фрейм
            while (elapsed >= _fireRate)
            {
                if (IsFire) // если флаг активен стреляем
                {
                    Shoot();
                    elapsed -= _fireRate;
                }
                else // если флаг не активен, прерываем корутину
                {
                    _firing = null;
                    yield break;
                }
            }
            elapsed += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }
    }

    private void Shoot ()
    {
        Instantiate(_bulletTemplate, _shootPoint.position, _shootPoint.rotation);
    }
}
```

Стрелять может и игрок, и враг, и ловушка, и что угодно, а `Input` - это абсолютно другая ответственность, и в пределах одного класса их вместе быть не должно!

Comment: Всё так, но почему скорость то у лазеров разная? Потому что у первых двух заспавненных лазеров скорость будет одна, а у следующих двух другая, т.к. deltaTime будет отличаться