# Какая из данных функций оптимальнее?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как вы считаете какую из функций оптимальнее использовать для перемещения 2D игрока под android?

1.

```
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.Translate(new Vector2(x, y) * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

2. 

```
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.MovePosition(rb.position + new Vector2(x, y) * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Функция `Update` запускается ровно один раз в каждом кадре, тогда как функция `FixedUpdate` запускается с фиксированным интервалом, не зависящим от частоты кадров вашей игры, что позволяет запускать ее один раз, ноль или несколько раз за кадр.

Так что `FixedUpdate` подходит больше для физических действий(передвижение, прыжок и т.д.) не зависимо под какую платформу вы делайте игру.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ:)