# Не получается сделать прыжок в UNITY 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал прыжок в unity 2D, но он получился очень резким, будто персонаж телепортируется, поэтому попытался сделать другой, но теперь он вообще не прыгает. Прочел этот пост, но всеравно не получилось -> [link](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0)
При таком случае не прыгает:

```
rb.AddForce(transform.up * jumpforce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
```

При таком прыгает:

```
rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpforce);
```

Мучась с прыжком, не могу сделать нормальный, плавный прыжок.

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй это добавить что-ли
GetComponent ().AddForce (Vector2.up * force); //force = 300

Comment: Больше помочь ничем не могу, но попробуй в Ютубе посмотреть

Comment: Спасибо за попытку, но у меня именно такое и написано.