# Плавно передвижение объекта в конкретную позицию. Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

При вхождении персонажа в триггер зону, сделать чтобы срабатывал метод, который плавно передвигает персонажа с текущей позиции, в назначенную.
Пытался через всякие MoveTowards, Корутины и, получалось может-быть что-то, но какие-то костыли, хотелось бы увидеть код) либо услышать в каком направлении мне двигаться

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%81%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0)

Comment: абсолютно неясно необходимо перемещать по прямой линии или по пути или же что бы персонаж добираться из одной точки в другую используя ИИ. В общем - совсем неконкретный вопрос на который неясно как отвечать

Answer (score 0):

Здесь будет назначенная позиция

```
public Transform target;
```

Направление

```
private Vector3 d;
```

Скорость

```
public float speed = 5f;
```

В методе Update() записываем

```
d = Vector3.RotateTowards(transform.forward, target.position - transform.position, .01f, 10);
transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(d);
transform.position += transform.forward * speed * Time.DeltaTime;
```

Еще один вариант через тот же MoveTowards

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, speed);
```