# C#, в Unity Не работает прыжок

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public class Hiro : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private float speed = 3f;
    [SerializeField] private int lives = 5;
    [SerializeField] private float jampForce = 15f;

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private SpriteRenderer sprite;

    private void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>(); 
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
            Run();
        if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            Run();
    }

    private void Run()
    {
        Vector3 dir = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + dir, speed * Time.deltaTime);
           
        sprite.flipX = dir.x < 0.0f;
    }
    private void Jump()
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.up * jampForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (Input.GetButton("Jump")) Run();`? Внимательность!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

Comment: простите, я новичок в этом и не понимаю в чем ошибка, по точнее объяснить. пожалуста!!!

Comment: я сейчас проверяю, и прикол в том что оно работает как ускорение

Comment: спасибо я понял в чем ошибка

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Hiro : MonoBehaviour
{
[SerializeField] private float speed = 3f;
[SerializeField] private int lives = 5;
[SerializeField] private float jampForce = 15f;

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private SpriteRenderer sprite;

private void Awake()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    sprite = GetComponentInChildren<SpriteRenderer>(); 
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButton("Horizontal"))
        Run();
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
        Jump();
}

private void Run()
{
    Vector3 dir = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, transform.position + dir, speed * Time.deltaTime);
       
    sprite.flipX = dir.x < 0.0f;
}
private void Jump()
{
    rb.AddForce(transform.up * jampForce, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```

}

Ты забыл поменять в Update() функцию с Run() на Jump()