# аниматор не отрабатывает один if?

Tags: c#, unity3d, animator

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
[RequireComponent(typeof(UnitMovement), typeof(Animator))]

public class UnitSkin : MonoBehaviour 
{
    private Animator _animator;
    private UnitMovement _unit;

    private void Awake()
        {
           _animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isJump", true);
        }
        else
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isJump", false);
        }
        
        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isWalk", true);
        }
        else
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isWalk", false);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isWalk", true);
        }
        else
        {
            _animator.SetBool("isWalk", false);
        }
    }
}
```

в итоге не включается анимация при нажатии на leftArrow

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Почитайте еще это: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

Comment: Да, спасибо! учусь потихоньку)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Логику движения обычно в FixedUpdate пишут.

Суть проблемы в том, что логика реакции на стрелку вправо перекрывает логику реакции на стрелку влево, здесь достаточно добавить "или" `||`.

Попробуйте выполнить свой код пошагово, и увидите, что `_animator.SetBool("isWalk",...)` отработает дважды, логично что эффект будет только от последнего.

```
void FixedUpdate()
{
    bool isJump = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow);
    _animator.SetBool("isJump", isJump);

    bool isWalk = Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow);
    _animator.SetBool("isWalk", isWalk);
}
```