# Падает FPS при уничтожении объекта в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я делаю подбирание предмета, и мне нужно уничтожать объект и добавлять к переменной количества, и при уничтожение фпс падает с ~40 до ~10, я уже пробовал использовать `SetActive(true)`, но то же самое.

Код уничтожения >>

```
using UnityEngine;

public class GetTarget : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("Предметы")]
    public static int stick = 0;
    public static int stone = 0;
    public static int tree = 0;

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider) 
    {
        if(collider.CompareTag("Ground") && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            return;
        }
        else if(collider.CompareTag("Stick") && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            stick++;
            Destroy(collider.gameObject);
        }
        else if(collider.CompareTag("Tree") && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            tree++;
            Destroy(collider.gameObject);
        }
        else
        {
            if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                collider.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Просадки будут при любом использовании Destroy() и чём тяжелее объект тем должно будет проводиться удаление, это очень дорогостоящая операция, чтобы не терять производительности при уничтожении чего то многочисленного как монетки лучше использовать Object Pool, капайте в эту сторону

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую сделать так!

Comment: Как я понял Object Pool - это предварительное создание объектов на сцене, но у меня их десятки тысяч =(

Comment: Так для этого этот паттерн и создан, вы создаёте пул из 50 к примеру заранее, и вместо уничтожения вы скрываете и открываете когда вам нужно, у вас всегда остается 50 обьектов ничего не уничтожается, тут вместо 50 можете указать количество которое может быть одновременно, потому что скрытый обьект снова может быть показан и так можно добиться сильной оптимизации

Comment: Только не забывайте что пул создает дополнительные трудности, так как вы обьект не пересоздаёте его при скрытии или показе нужно переинициализировать если на нём висел скрипт с параметрами

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Этот метод можно оптимизировать, очевидно, что если мышь не нажата, то метод ничего не делает, тогда зачем эту мышь проверять 4 раза? Доступ к тегу коллайдера тоже можно использовать один раз.

```
private void OnTriggerStay(Collider collider) 
{
    if (!Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        return;

    switch (collider.tag)
    {
        case "Stick":
            stick++;
            break;
        case "Tree":
            tree++;
            break;
        default:
            return; // случай с Ground тоже попадает сюда
    }
    Destroy(collider.gameObject);
}
```

Не факт, что это гарантированно спасёт от просадок, но метод будет бодрее работать.

Досконально механику Unity не знаю, но можете проверить, сколько раз вызывается `Destroy`. Для этого добавьте в конец метода

```
Debug.Log(collider.tag + " destroyed.");
```

И посчитайте, по сколько раз для каждого объекта производится вывод в отладочную консоль. Если по одному разу, то проблема тормозов не в этом коде, а где-то в другом месте.

Если же вывод для удаляемого объекта несколько раз, то метод придется пропатчить, чтобы `Destroy` не вызывался повторно.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Я полностью переделал код и получилось в 2 - 3 раза меньше лагов!

Comment: @ForTankista что именно из ответа помогло? просто интересно

Comment: Сам до конца не понял, но вроде проверка на нажата ли кнопка или нет + проверка на объект.

Comment: Я про switch забыл и использовал if - else if, код получился по длинней, но как по мне понятнее с использованием switch.

Comment: @ForTankista ничего страшного, с опытом освоитесь. `if` не медленнее работает, просто выглядит более громозским.

Comment: Возможно ещё то что я добавил break; в конце кода уничтожения / подбирания, типо оно прекращает действие кода. Я не очень программист поэтому я могу ошибаться.

Comment: Я просто слышал что if - else if - это плохо и так делать нельзя.

Comment: @ForTankista есть такой принцип DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) "не повторяй за собой". Если приходится писать повторяющийся код, значит что-то пошло не так. Будьте внимательны.

Comment: В этом случие можете мне ещё раз помочь, если не сложно, switch >> case "Если коротко говоря": Я делал управление персонажем и так получилась что вышло Ctrl + C - Ctrl + V, я смотрел другие видео об этом и понял что будет в 100 раз проще оставить так. Новый вопрос.

Comment: @ForTankista можете задать отдельный вопрос. Либо я, либо кто-то другой поможет.

Comment: @ForTankista https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

Comment: Вау! Спасибо, просмотрю!