# Как реализовать перелезания на объект в Unity2D?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я столкнулся с такой проблемой: коллайдер игрока устроен таким образом, что при прыжке игрок может зацепится коллайдером руки за платформу, а сам игрок будет в воздухе, и на платформу забраться не сможет. Я уже нацепил на гейм обжект руки с коллайдером скрипт, который по идеи должен при контакте с платформой подбрасывать игрока, но скрипт не работает. Я делал это через RigidBody.AddForce, и возможно скрипт не может получить RigidBody персонажа. Если что, код скрипта:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ArmTriggerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform player;

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    player.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>().AddForce(Vector2.up * 10f);
    Debug.Log("Получилось");
}
}
```

Как это должно выглядить: [image]

Comment: Картинки нарисуй по кадрам, что хочешь сделать, иначе трудно подсказать как это можно реализовать.

Comment: Обновил, его должно подкинуть прямо на платформу, если он застрял на коллайдере руки.

Comment: советую заменить меш коллайдер на капсульКоллайдер и никаких проблем. Меш коллайдер необходимо использовать только если на это есть реальные причины какие-то. Подозреваю что здесь их нет

Comment: А насчёт использования бокс коллайдера?

Comment: @Zenith бокс более плохой вариант во-первых из-за углов(которые могут за что-то зацеплятся), а во-вторых из-за большей площади трения. Двигать обьекты необходимо физически, иначе это вызовет кучи проблем в будущем. В общем об этом можно почитать здесь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/186752

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно триггер поставить на край платформы.

1. Как только персонаж попадает в триггер - отключаем управление (в твоём случае и Rigigbody как я понял).
2. Проигрываем анимацию как персонаж залезает на край платформы.
3. Включаем управление обратно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Как переместить персонажа на платформу? С помощью AddForce?

Comment: Окей, смог с помощью триггера реализовать. Спасибо.