# Почему прыжок работает неправильно?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Хотел сделать прыжок в Unity2d, что только не пробывал,делал его через rb.velocity по итогу обьект просто не прыгал. Помогите исправить!!!
`public class PlayerJump : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public float JumpForce;
private bool isGround;
Rigidbody2D rb;







public void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

public void OnJump()
{

    if (isGround == true)
        rb.velocity = Vector2.up * JumpForce;


}

private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
    {
        isGround = true;
        
    }

}
private void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Platform")
    {
        isGround = false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Точно не могу сказать в чем проблема, поэтому приведу все варианты возникновения

1. Функция OnJump ни к чему не привязана. То есть она просто не вызывается
2. На платформе не висит тэг "Platform", из-за этого isGround всегда false
3. На платформе должен быть collider2d и на игроке должен быть collider2d и rigidbody2d
4. Также возможно стоит попробовать velocity заменить на addforce: `_rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * JumpForce);`
   Ну а если ничего не помогло, то вот пост, где подробно рассказано о движении: [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0)

Comment: Здравствуйте
1.Этот скрипт в проекте привязан к обьекту ,а функция OnJump вызывается через Button
2.На платформе тег тоже висит и коллайдеры тоже 
3. _rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpForce); такой способ уже пробывал , по итогу обьект резко телепортируется вверх (так же хотелось подметить что если поставить в JumpForce значение 10,то персонаж не прыгает ,прыжки начинаются только когда значение становится ближе к 1000)  , если есть возможность подскажите как это исправить пожалуйста,буду очень благодарен
Статью уже смотрел и не раз

Comment: Используйте addforce, я считаю это самым лучшим вариантом. А чтобы все выглядело реалистично поиграйтесь с силой толчка и весом вашего rigidbody, также можно попробовать поменять ForceMode у Addforce. Вот ссылка: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ForceMode.html. Кстати, должен быть Vector2.up у меня опечатка.

Comment: 1.Уже 1 час игрался со значениями ,но ничего не помогло ,соровно какое бы значение не стояло в JumpForce обьект телепортировался вверх
2.Так же хотел спросить ,почему когда решил попробывать реализовать движение по горизонтале через AddForce ,всё стало работать ?Это может быть связанно?(Имею ввиду ,что нельзя на один обьект через скрипт воздействовать 2 силами)

Comment: 1. Не знаю почему так. У человека здесь(https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/936026/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0) все корректно работает и у вас значит должно. 2. Фактически идет симуляция физических процессов, движение горизонтально отличается от вертикального, это не баг Unity. Вроде движением занимается раздел физики - кинематика

Comment: Вообщем я смог решить проблему ,она заключалась в том что в моём другом скрипте была строка rb.velocity = new Vector (x , 0) из за которой как я понял значение толчка просто обнулялось 
Благодарю вас за оказанную помощь

Comment: Рад что у вас получилось. Удачи вам в дальнейшей работе