# При float менее 0.2f Unity не прибавляет ускорение объекту

Tags: c#, unity3d, float

Господа!
Такая проблема: хочу сделать простенькую игрульку в Unity 3D, а-ля драг-рейсинг. Как известно, такая игра - ничто, если в ней нет равномерного ускорения. И чтобы сделать его, я обратился к прибавлению float = 0,1f к начальной скорости в FixedUpdate (т.к комп достаточно мощный и в простом Update машинка быстро выйдет на сверхзвук).
Проблема в том, что при прибавлении 0,1f, значение текущей скорости начинает хаотично меняться, где-то далеко после запятой и машинка не двигается. Отследил значения переменной скорости, а там, что-то вроде "0,0012637963-5е". Такое же безобразие при 0,19f. Но стоит только установить 0,2f или больше, как всё начинает прекрасно работать.
Поскольку, хочется реализовать режим прокачки автомобиля, то 0,2f многовато для начала и хочется получить изначально машинку гораздо медленнее. Как победить непонятные вычисления Unity? Заранее благодарю! Ниже сокращенный код класса:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class DragCar: MonoBehaviour
{

    private float _acceleration = 0.1f;   // *если здесь меньше 0,2f то ничего не работает*
    private float _maxSpeed = 100f;
    private float _speed = 0;

    [SerializeField] private float _currentSpeed = 1f;
    [SerializeField] private float _visualCurrentSpeed = 0;

    private Rigidbody _rb;


    void Start()
    {
        _rb= GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }


    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        _visualCurrentSpeed = _rb.velocity.z * 3.6f;
        _currentSpeed = _rb.velocity.z;

      if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
      {   
        if (_currentSpeed >= _maxSpeed) 
         { 
           _speed = _maxSpeed;
           _rb.velocity = new(0, 0, _speed);
         }
         else 
         {
           _rb.velocity = new(0, 0, _currentSpeed + _acceleration);  //вот здесь всё ломается          
         }
            
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Запустите игру и подольше последите за движущимся объектом. Скорее всего он очень медленно ускоряется.

Comment: Боюсь это не так. Поскольку, при 0.2f, объект разгоняется до скорости 10f уже через 2 секунды. Значит при 0,1f должен разгоняться за 4 секунды. Ну или по крайней мере начать видимое движение. Тут же не происходит ничего. Объект стоит на месте, даже после 10 секунд удержания нажатой клавиши. При 0,19f происходит то же самое. Начинает работать только начиная с 0,2f и больше.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Информация в посте по ссылке ОЧЕНЬ ПОЛЕЗНАЯ! Но не нашёл связи с проблемой описаной в вопросе. Хотелось бы понять в чем проблема с вычислениями. Как может всё прекрасно работать с 0.2f и не работать уже при 0.19f

Answer (score 0):

Большое спасибо, Господину aepot и всем кто отозвался! Разобраться с вопросом почему Unity так делает вычисления не получилось, но проблему удалось решить (благодаря правильным мыслям прочитанным по ссылке от aepot) удалением переменной _curerentSpeed из вычисления вектора скорости и установки на её место итератора ++ _acceleration и умножением его на Time.fixedDeltaTime. Получилась такая строка:

```
_rb.velocity = new(0, 0, ++ _acceleration * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
```

Теперь, ускорение можно задавать даже как 0,001f.