# Ошибка в Rigidbody.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

Tags: c#, unity3d

Есть код:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody move;
    void Awake()
    {
        private Rigidbody _move = move.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
}
```

При компиляции в Unity3d, выдает две ошибки: CS1513 и CS1022.

При взятии в комментарий эту строку кода, компилируется без проблем:
`// private Rigidbody _move = move.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();`

Как решить эту проблему, чтобы `move.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` работал?

Comment: петька, приборы! ­— "CS1513 и CS1022"! — что "CS1513 и CS1022'? — а что "приборы"? // приведите, пожалуйста, **полные** тексты (именно тексты) сообщений об ошибах.

Comment: *"Как решить эту проблему"* --- для начала надо прочитать хотя бы одну книгу для новичков по тому языку, на котором пишете))

Comment: почему в методе есть переменная у которой проставлен модификатор доступа? ..... а что значит строка `Rigidbody _move = move.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` ??? Можете объяснить?

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin эти ошибки можно на сайте msdn посмотреть на самом деле  https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs1513 .... там они все....ну это я так... просто

Comment: Нужна она для управления элементами физики объекта, в данном случае для объекта Player. С помощью его можно управлять массой, и.т.п. В самом редакторе закрывающая фигурная скобка метода Await() связана с открывающей фигурной скобкой класса MovePlayer, как раз таки из-за этого и вызывается ошибка.

Comment: вы не ответили на вопрос про модификатор доступа - раз........... второе *"Нужна она для управления элементами физики объекта, в данном случае для объекта Player"* --- фраза ни о чём не говорит.... давайте по порядку..... что делает конструкция `move.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();` ?

Comment: Человек хочет сказать слово "Азбука", не выучив букву "A" для начала, о чем тут говорить? Проблема в том что основ языка не знает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из показанного кода несовсем понятно, что вы хотите сделать.

Если хотите получить компонент текущего объекта, то это делается просто

```
public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody body; // не нужно его сериализовать или делать публичным, так как в редакторе этот компонент и так доступен

    void Awake()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
}
```

Если другого объекта, то как-то так

```
public class MovePlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private GameObject otherObject; // сюда в Unity Editor навешивается ссылка на другой объект
    private Rigidbody otherBody;

    void Awake()
    {
        otherBody = otherObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
}
```

Собственно, ничего другого здесь не придумать, задача простейшая.

Ну и стоит подучить C# прежде чем далее углубляться в Unity, а именно стоит узнать:

- Что такое классы и объекты
- Что такое члены класса и модификаторы доступа
- Что такое переменные в методах

В куске вашего кода вы пытаетесь объявить уже объявленный член класса внутри метода, это недопустимо и говорит только о том, что вы даже не подозреваете, что это недопустимо. Поэтому надо учить язык. [Начните с простого](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLuGqgO5WmeGPTZqDHZDIum3h7HnfBfzmZ), уделите пару вечеров и код станет намного понятнее. Все эти видосики на ютубе "Игра за 24 часа" - уловка, обман. Невозможно просто так взять и без понимания основ что-либо вменяемое написать.

Я сам очень хорошо знаю C#, но при изучении Unity у меня до сих пор возникают трудности. А каково вам, если даже основы языка не знаете?

Дополнительно, если вопрос касается передвижения персонажа, то почитайте этот ответ:

- [Правильная реализация передвижения персонажа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/936026/373567)